# Diamond creator +

Tags: code-golf, ascii-art, geometry

## Challenge :

Given an integer `n` as input. Create a diamond that is 2x the given number `n`.

## Input :

Input is integer `n` and 2 < n ≤ 3000.

## Output :

Output will be a string and it will be in form of a diamond consisting of `+` with an addition line at the start showing `n` using `+`

## Examples :

```
D(3) :

+++
  +
 +++
+++++
+++++
 +++
  +

D(5) :

+++++
    +
   +++
  +++++
 +++++++
+++++++++
+++++++++
 +++++++
  +++++
   +++
    +

D(6) : 

++++++
     +
    +++
   +++++
  +++++++
 +++++++++
+++++++++++
+++++++++++
 +++++++++
  +++++++
   +++++
    +++
     +
```

## Winning Criteria :

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf) so shortest code in bytes for each programming language wins.

Comment: [Related: Print this diamond](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/8696/print-this-diamond) and [related: User Scored Code Golf - Drawing Diamonds](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/45040/user-scored-code-golf-drawing-diamonds-experimental)

Comment: @KevinCruijssen : Um so is this ok , or should I remove this ?

Comment: No it's ok. It's related, not a duplicate. :) Related challenges are just linked as inspiration, but yours is different enough (imo) to not be closed as a dupe.

Comment: @KevinCruijssen : Ok so it can stay ?

Comment: @KevinCruijssen : I see , i'm still new so learning the rules , thanks for telling me.

Comment: May we take `n` in unary?

Comment: … using `+` as [tally mark](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unary_numeral_system)?

Comment: @Adám : I guess you can if you feel like the normal doesn't work

Comment: Can you add a test case where `n` is even?

Comment: @Shaggy : sure why not. I will add that right away. Thanks

Comment: @Shaggy : There implemented.

Comment: @Adám [here is the meta post on unary I/O](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5343/can-numeric-input-output-be-in-unary)

Comment: This is a grenade.

Answer (score 36):

## [brainfuck](https://github.com/TryItOnline/brainfuck), <s>151</s> 139 bytes

```
,[.[<]<+[>>]++++[-<++++++++>],]<[<]<<<++++++++++.>>[[>]>[-<+>]>[-<+>]>>[.>>]<<[<]<<.<<[..<<]<.>>-]>[[>]>[.>>]<<[<<]>.>>[..>>]<<,<[<]<<.>>>]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RY1RCoBACEQP5K4nkLmIzEcFQQR9BJ3f3HYrPxxmfOp8TtuxXsseUVzdaOIAJcurySiw0NrQvkhEAXcQjfsFnnmCD62pmo2WYeXgX8CIdkO7L2MF6SL6ixs)

Takes input via unary, with `+`s as tally marks ([allowed by the poster](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/162798/diamond-creator/162810#comment394423_162798)). Decided to rework this, as I thought the old one was a bit longer than it could be (though this one is too!).

#### Old Version (151 bytes):

```
>--[>+<++++++]<[->+>.<<]++++++++[-<+<++++>>]<++>>[<<.>>-[-<+<<.>>>]<[->+<]>>>+[-<.>>+<]>+[-<+>]<<<]>>[<<<<.>>[-<+<<.>>>]<[->+<]>+>>-[-<.>>+<]>-[-<+>]<]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bYxBCoBQCEQPJHaCYS4iLioIImgRdH5T/182C3FmfG7Pet7Hu18hpaCqUdBGHKYULoDLlClGSzpqGrCQ2nltHBA817rOqEyD2aGKZPr2B5Lxa1I6KY/4AA)

Takes input as the starting cell. I couldn't think of a way to leverage the first half to help with the second, so there's a loop for each of them.

#### How It Works:

```
 >--[>+<++++++]  Create 43 ('+') two space to the left of n
 <[->+>.<<]      Print n '+'s while preserving n
 ++++++++[-<+<++++>>]<++  Create 32 (' ') and 10 ('\n')
                         Tape: 32 10 0 n 43 t
 >>
 [ Loop over the first half of the diamond
   <<.>>         Print a newline
   -[-<+<<.>>>]  Decrement n and print n spaces
   <[->+<]       Restore n
   >>>+[-<.>>+<] Increment t and print t '+'s
   >+[-<+>]<<<   Increment t again and restore it
]>>
[ Loop over the second half
  <<<<.>>        Print a newline
  [-<+<<.>>>]<   Print n spaces
  [->+<]>+       Restore and increment n
  >>-[-<.>>+<]   Decrement t and print t '+'s
  >-[-<+>]<      Decrement t again and restore it
]
```

And just for fun:

```
+++++++++
        >
       --[
      >+<++
     ++++]<[
    ->+>.<<]+
   +++++++[-<+
  <++++>>]<++>>
 [<<.>>-[-<+<<.>
>>]<[->+<]>>>+[-<
.>>+<]>+[-<+>]<<<
 ]>>[<<<<.>>[-<+
  <<.>>>]<[->+<
   ]>+>>-[-<.>
    >+<]>-[-<
     +>]<]++
      +++++
       +++
        +
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VY9LCgMxDEP3PkX2wTmB0EVCFtNCoRRmUej5M1Y@pfUiyMhPsW/v43k@PvdX73mXpVXcyr0uyYw9oNGGaTgzC9CGtWKqQy2kyQa9lipQSJcpZXJq4GgkxVjY6gYfJmApvOAGuVOlN6pPA5ixZW49MtSvZWO2fU/7O/P34tz7BQ)

Comment: You got my vote for the just for the fun thing. Cool answer

Answer (score 16):

## [Canvas](https://github.com/dzaima/Canvas), 9 [bytes](https://github.com/dzaima/Canvas/blob/master/files/chartable.md)

```
+×Ｏ｛+×］±╪
```

[Try it here!](https://dzaima.github.io/Canvas/?u=KyVENyV1RkYyRiV1RkY1QislRDcldUZGM0QlQjEldTI1NkE_,i=NQ__,v=2)

Explanation (some characters have been replaced to look monospace):

```
+×O{+×]±╪
+×         repeat "+" input times
  O        output that
   {  ]    map over 1..input
    +×       repeat "+" that many times
       ±   interpret the array as a 2D string, and reverse it
        ╪  quad-palindromize with 1 horizontal overlap and 0 vertical overlap
```

Answer (score 13):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), <strike>95</strike> <strike>94</strike> 75 bytes

```python
def f(n):a=[' '*(n+~i)+'+'*(i-~i)for i in range(n)];return['+'*n]+a+a[::-1]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FYoxDkIhEAWvsh2L5Bt/7DCeBClIBF2LB9nwCxuvjjDVTDLt298V1zGeuVBhWJ/uwZA5MdxPrDNuqmxTS1USEpAmvPI8401zPxRhPYguuRS83/Y4mgo6mwfM@VMFXHi1oB2d7WLslz8)

---

My first attempt at some golfing, any suggestions for improvement are welcome.

EDIT: saved 1 byte thanks to Kevin Cruijssen

EDIT: removed misunderstanding about byte count

EDIT: Saved many more bytes thanks to Jo King and user202729

Comment: Welcome to PPCG! :)

Comment: Also, if you change to Python 2, `print'\n'.join(['+'*n]+a+a[::-1])` can be used without parenthesis to save 2 more bytes. +1 from me though. Nice first answer. :)

Comment: Wow, I didn't know that the `~` operator worked like that for integers. I'll stick to Python 3 for now, as I have very limited experience with Python 2, and someone else could probably come up with a better solution. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Your byte-count is wrong (was correct previously). If you define a function that returns the result, you can use the footer to call that function and display the result. You can't do part of the challenge in the footer and not count those bytes.

Comment: I reverted to the previous edit. I was just a bit confused as the other Python answer had a bit of logic in the footer, I'll try to read up on the rules.

Comment: @JoKing I saw that you used that approach in your answer, is there any consensus on what is allowed in the footer and what isn't?

Comment: Submissions can be either a full program (nothing in header/footer) or a function (which must defines a function (or reference, in case of anonymous function such as `lambda`)).

Comment: In this case it's allowed to return a list of lines.

Comment: And, `2*i+1 == i+i+1 == i-(-i-1) == i-~i`.

Comment: Great first answer. well done.

Answer (score 9):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 14 bytes

```
'+×sL·<'+×∊.c»
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##MzBNTDJM/f9fXfvw9GKfQ9ttQIxHHV16yYd2//9vCgA)

**Explanation**

```
'+×              # push "+" repeated <input> times
   sL            # push range [1 ... input]
     ·<          # multiply each element by 2 and decrement (x*2-1)
       '+×       # replace each number with the corresponding number of "+"'s
          ∊      # mirror vertically
           .c    # center
             »   # join with the "+"-row created at the start
```

Also 14 bytes: `L‚˜'+×ćs.∞∊.c»`

Comment: `'+×s·ÅÉ'+×∊.C»` using `ÅÉ` is another

Comment: @MagicOctopusUrn: My initial thought was using `ÅÉ` but I discarded it because I didn't think of using `·` to make it work.

Comment: `sL` can be `ā` for -1

Answer (score 5):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), <s>79</s> 78 bytes

```python
def f(n):x=[('++'*i+'+').center(n*2)for i in range(n)];return[n*'+']+x+x[::-1]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FcpBDsIgEEbhq7CbgYmN1R3GkyALo6C4@GkmNKGnx/btXvItW/tWXMd4p2wyw/p@D0wi5IqQkJ1eCS0pw11srmqKKTD6xCftON40tVUR4HYbpUsP3p/mOBYtaEwP0PSrBZz5@IJlbWyPxnz@Aw)

Thanks to this [Tips for golfing Python](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/98613/76162) answer for informing me about the `.center` function. Returns a list of strings.

Comment: Isn't the footer included in the byte count? In that case, my solution is 58 bytes

Comment: @maxb If you're using a function, it is generally okay to return output as a list of lines

Comment: @JoKing : Hum might wanna do a lil recheck ? [TRY](https://tio.run/##ZYzBDsIgDIbvPAW3Ao1L3G4YbnsL5GCUKR7KQliCT4/M6S7@h/Zv@/WfX/kRaaj15ic@CpK6GCsAQfUqYOuyu3rKPglSvZxi4oEH4ulCd99od0o@L4ksqcY6LFis1oejq3MKlAWcCbpnDCRGMUjJjWEAgKsYb/rUbfgucRND/Hf7cad/z2tSC5b1DQ)

Comment: @JoKing : It fails.

Comment: @MuhammadSalman 1. You’re testing my function for n=3 against the return for n=5, 2. You have a trailing newline in the test, and 3. My code has trailing spaces on each line. Maybe you should just *look* at the output next time

Comment: @JoKing : 1). oops. My bad forgot to change it back to 5. 2). Hum , well I guess that works too. Cool

Comment: @JoKing : Apologies for inconvenience

Comment: You can do this in 75 bytes by calculating the number of spaces: `def f(n):x=[' '*(n+~i)+'++'*i+'+'for i in range(n)];return[n*'+']+x+x[::-1]`

Comment: Eh, it ends up being a copy of maxb's answer

Answer (score 4):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), <s>135 110</s> 96 bytes

```r
function(n){cat("+"<n,"
",sep="")
for(i in c(1:n,n:1))cat(" "<n-i,"+"<2*i-1,"
",sep="")}
"<"=rep
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Tcs7DoAgDADQnVOQTq3CgIMDgcMYYpMu1aBOxrPjZ3J/rza2yTc@tOyyKCqdZdoRekjqwIDb5jUDkOGlolhRWzBEdRoD0SftI724dwyd@PBfl4EEuc5rYxyp3Q)

@JayCe with the final cut.

The `rep` function is assigned to an existing infix operator, such as `<` or `^` so that `rep("+", n)` is equivalent to `"<"("+", n)` which can be written out using `<` as an infix operator as in `"+" < n` and shortened to `"+"<n`.

Comment: [Save 25 bytes](https://tio.run/##VcwhDoAwDEBRv1M0VS10YggEgcOQZUtqChlgIJx9CAz4/36pGUZf82Fx18XI5JywRb5cnHcqaaVTjAUdypbWCZFdXgqQghpECoOJDYE/PQKKeWV5cdeoD7/BfddMPdcH) and make it a function.

Comment: So totally your answer :) Great original code!

Comment: There's some whitespace here that can be removed, and using `"+"` directly instead of saving it as `z` saves some bytes! [Try it here](https://tio.run/##VcsxDoAgDADAnVeQTq2WAQcHoo8xRJIulSBOxrejiybud6UlO7mWDo1VNkWlMy4Vy5oRemAlBgO8r3kGIJO2gmJFbUQflDV4oo/bhzshfu/QifO/f7WEI7Ub)

Comment: @ngm @Giuseppe On top of Giuseppe's improvement, substitute `<` for `rep` to get under 100 chars! [Here](https://tio.run/##Tcs7DoAgDADQnVOQTq3CgIMDgcMYYpMu1aBOxrPjZ3J/rza2yTc@tOyyKCqdZdoRekjqwIDb5jUDkOGlolhRWzBEdRoD0SftI724dwyd@PBfl4EEuc5rYxyp3Q)

Answer (score 3):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 15 bytes

```
Ｇ→→↙Ｎ+↓‖Ｍ↑×⊕ⅈ+‖
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RYyxCsJAEER7vyKk2sNY2iStTcBICAq28dwkB3e7Yd1E/PrzENFqZh4zY6deLPc@xpb9a2SCsnPjpEX20wM/6YhDsjXNi56WcEMBU2T5NjfVpuEV4VNKocPBo9XGibBAeZkTa8WRwtkFfEBNVjAgKd7hCuZ78h@CqWLcx93q3w) Link is to verbose version of code. Explanation:

```
Ｇ→→↙Ｎ+
```

Print an inverted triangle of `+`s the height of the input and almost twice the width.

```
↓
```

Move the cursor down so it lands on the additional line after the reflection.

```
‖Ｍ↑
```

Make a mirror image of the triangle.

```
×⊕ⅈ+
```

Draw the additional line using the current column to avoid having to read the input again.

```
‖
```

Reflect the output so that the additional line points to the left.

Answer (score 3):

## [J](http://jsoftware.com/), <s>29</s> 22 bytes

-7 bytes thanks to Jonah!

```
' +'{~#&1,]>:[:+/~|@i:
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y/qvpKeepmBrpaCuoKNgoGAFxLp6Cs5BPm7/1RW01avrlNUMdWLtrKKttPXrahwyrf5rcqUmZ@QrpCmY/gcA)

#### Original solution:

## [J](http://jsoftware.com/), 29 bytes

```
'+'(,]\(}:@|."1,.])@,]\.)@$~]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y/qvpKeepmBrpaCuoKNgoGAFxLp6Cs5BPm7/1bXVNXRiYzRqrRxq9JQMdfRiNR2AfD1NB5W62P@aXApcqckZ@QppCsYwhimMYWjC9R8A)

### Explanation:

```
'+'$~] - generates the line at the start, which is a seed for the diamond:

   '+'$~]  3
+++

]\,]\. - finds the prefixes (]\) and suffixes (]\.) of the line, making "half" the diamond 

   '+'(]\,]\.)@$~] 3
+  
++ 
+++
+++
++ 
+  

}:@|."1,.] - makes the other "half" of the diamond by reversing each line (|."1)
and dropping its last '+' (}:) and stitches the first half to it (,.])

 '+'(]\(}:@|."1,.])@,]\.)@$~] 3
  +  
 +++ 
+++++
+++++
 +++ 
  +  

, - prepends the initial line to the diamond

'+'(,]\(}:@|."1,.])@,]\.)@$~] 3
+++  
  +  
 +++ 
+++++
+++++
 +++ 
  +
```

Comment: 25 - `' +'{~1"+@i.,]>:[:+/~|@i:` - [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y/qvpKeepmBrpaCuoKNgoGAFxLp6Cs5BPm7/1RW01avrDJW0HTL1dGLtrKKttPXrahwyrf5rcqUmZ@QrpCmY/gcA "J – Try It Online")

Comment: @Jonah Thanks! I have forgotten this one...

Comment: Just popped in my feed. Also, just realized we can go to 22: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y/qvpKeepmBrpaCuoKNgoGAFxLp6Cs5BPm7/1RW01avrlNUMdWLtrKKttPXrahwyrf5rcqUmZ@QrpCmY/gcA "J – Try It Online")

Answer (score 3):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), <s>76</s> 75 bytes

```python
lambda n:['+'*n]+[' '*(n+~i)+'+'*(i-~i)for i in[*range(n),*range(n)[::-1]]]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PcixDoIwEAbgV@l2d60YiVsTn6R0KNHCGf1LGhYWXr3I4vblW7Z1Lri3/BjaJ33HZzLwgRxZRBfIkGW4XcWdxdr9mEs1ahTB1oTpxZDLX8H7ro8xtqUqVqYBdH0XBWfubyLSDg)

Answer (score 3):

## [Stax](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax), 11 [bytes](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax/blob/master/docs/packed.md#packed-stax)

```
ñ1┌╙@↔g+┤a☻
```

[Run and debug it](https://staxlang.xyz/#p=a431dad3401d672bb46102&i=9&a=1)

Answer (score 3):

### QB64, <strike>82</strike> 79 bytes

```
INPUT n
?STRING$(n,43):FOR a=1TO 2*n:d=a-(a>n)*2*(n-a):?SPC(n-d);STRING$(2*d-1,43):NEXT
```

Comment: Welcome to PPCG! This is a great first submission, and I've added it to the list of solutions posted while [QBasic is Language of the Month](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/16480/16766). If you like, you can improve this answer by adding a short explanation. Enjoy your time here!

Answer (score 3):

## [Scala](http://www.scala-lang.org/), <del>95</del> 94 bytes

saved 1 byte(s) thanks to the comment.

---

Golfed version. [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JY3BCsIwDIbve4rQU2phbB4nEzx68DQ8qYc4O6l2UbtuIGO@@mwVEgjf/4evq8nS/DjfdO1hR4ZhnC@6gQa52LKX5TiQBSoxg569scAybemJplwLEAv8GMVSCRXO5cKoXMrUPyr9WoXFiEOqKEzq9KBdp6c5AYiGNsiQ3LUrYOMcvQ@Vd4avJ1nAno2HEsbQBIh@p7veRtRgnskffoayt4z/KG3v/3cURxYyVqZkSuYv)

```scala
def f(n:Int)={val a=(0 until n).map(i=>" "*(~i+n)+"+"*(2*i+1)).toSeq;Seq("+"*n)++a++a.reverse}
```

Ungolfed version.

```scala
object Main {
  def f(n: Int): Array[String] = {
    val a = (0 until n).map(i => " "*(n-1-i) + "+"*(2*i+1)).toArray
    Array("+"*n) ++ a ++ a.reverse
  }

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    val result = f(10)
    println(result.mkString("\n"))
  }
}
```

Comment: `n-1-i` can be `~i+n` for -1 byte.

Answer (score 2):

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org), <strike>106</strike> 105 bytes

- thanks to @Kevin Cruijssen for reducing by 1 byte

```javascript
n=>[...Array(n*2+1)].map((_,i)=>" ".repeat(i?i>n?i+~n:n-i:0)+"+".repeat(i?i>n?4*n-2*i+1:i*2-1:n)).join`
`
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XY3NCoMwEITvPkXwlLg1VNtehCh9jlKaYLWs2I2oFHrpq6dW/KEedhiY@XYq8zJd3mLTh2TvhSuVI5VepJTntjVvTkEMkbjKp2k4v@1QqNRnvmyLpjA9xwxTyhA@lFCIyV6AD5vwGFAYBwhRgkEcRgkJISuLpD3tckudrQtZ2wcv@UEopQHAY2y4nwFYlU2JFoP@g6cJHAsjzOb2gq6fNm4Jl/YMj2PuCw)

### ________________________________________________

Second approach

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org), <strike>105</strike> <strike>100</strike> <strike>99</strike> 98 bytes

- thanks to @Kevin Cruijssen for reducing by 1 byte
- thanks to @ovs for reducing by 1 byte

```javascript
n=>[X="+"[r="repeat"](n),...x=[...X].map((_,i)=>" "[r](n+~i)+"+"[r](i-~i)),...x.reverse()].join`
`
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XY3PCsMgDIfvfQrxpGT1MnZMn6NQZEpnh6XTYkvZaa/unOsftkN@JOT7kl4vemqDHefS@ZuJHUaHVVMjBdoEpMGMRs9UMsdPQognNilrKR56ZOx6shwrShKZAHhZDlmTzJZp@BoimMWEyTAuRe@tU4WKrXeTH4wY/J117MwRFQAUhKT6NABHknWjeMpf8bKKGcgy2ehdPS79dftypzc5P4tv)

Comment: Just as a matter of convention, you should have your shortest submission at the top of your post if you have multiple approaches within it. This allows for other people to easily attempt the challenge, 
 search for their language, and see how they compare to your best answer (and is needed for scoreboards to work properly on challenges that have scoreboards)

Answer (score 2):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), <s>85</s> 82 bytes

<sup>Saved 3 bytes thanks to [nimi](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/34531/nimi)!</sup>

```hs
n!c=[1..n]>>c
f n|x<-[(n-i)!" "++(i*2-1)!"+"|i<-[1..n]]=unlines$n!"+":x++reverse x
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0gszk7Nyfn/P08x2TbaUE8vL9bOLpkrTSGvpsJGN1ojTzdTU1FJQUlbWyNTy0jXEMjRVqrJBEqB1cbalublZOalFqvkgSSsKrS1i1LLUouKUxUq/ucmZuYp2Cqk5HMpQEBBaUlwSZFPnoKKQpqCMVZRU6yiZv8B)

Comment: Using [this tip](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/177774/48198) you can get rid of the twice used variable `x` which saves 4 bytes: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bYyxDoIwFAB3vuLRMLSSkqDRwUAnR50cCUMDJb5YXklbnPz3GsPKjZfLvXR4G2sTzovzEW466urhyOEIHHijBIhE@dB2dVVRr9SQTUDtShbJhIJTzkp2FY3y5mN8MEXHSaLIGbCy5Hg4ylr8ky82clv0adZI0MLoMthY1viM/k5QwASnXXvetZf0Aw "Haskell – Try It Online")

Answer (score 2):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt) `-R`, <s>18</s> 17 bytes

```
õÈ+Y î+Ãû ê1 iUî+
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0osKPn///DWwx3akQqH12kfbj68W@HwKkOFzFAg7/9/YwXdIAA)

Answer (score 2):

## [PowerShell](https://github.com/TryItOnline/TioSetup/wiki/Powershell), 55 bytes

```powershell
param($l)'+'*$l;1..$l+$l..1|%{" "*($l-$_)+'+'*($_*2-1)}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8gvTy0qzkjNyfn/vyCxKDFXQyVHU11bXUslx9pQT08lR1slR0/PsEa1WklBSQsoqasSr6kNUqChEq9lpGuoWfv//39jAA)

Comment: Great answer but the character should be `+` instead of `x`. Also you can make your response a bit more community friendly by using [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8gvTy0qzkjNyfn/vyCxKDFXQyVHU11bXUslx9pQT08lR1slR0/PsEa1WklBSQsoqasSr6mtpA1ix2sZ6Rpq1v7//98YAA "PowerShell – Try It Online") and adding a link to your answer

Comment: Derp - can't believe I didn't see that. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 98 bytes

```python
def d(s):print("+"*s);t=[("+"*i).center(2*s-1)for i in range(1,2*s,2)];print("\n".join(t+t[::-1]))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Lcs7DsIwEEXRnlVYrublJzkRjSNWkqRA2IGhGEf2NKzeoIju6kj3@OgryVRriLsJVOCPzKJkW9sUzHpbzmQMjygaM41N6R32lA0bFpPv8ozkuh93I7b5f69ih3diIW118b53G1ADTbgEuqJ@AQ)

Readable version:

```python
def diamond(size):
    print(size * "+")
    top = [("+" * i).center(2*size - 1) for i in range(1, 2*size, 2)]
    print("\n".join(top))
    print("\n".join(reversed(top)))
```

Comment: Much better :) I formatted your entry so that it looks like other answers. You want want to visit tio.run it formats your answer for you and makes it easy for others to reproduce your code.

Answer (score 2):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), <s>9</s> 8 bytes

```
Dη€û.C∊»
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f/f5dz2R01rDu/Wc37U0XVo9///2mAAAA) Takes input in unary with `+` as a tally mark; allowed as per [OP's comment](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/162798/diamond-creator?page=2&tab=oldest#comment394399_162798).

```
Dη€û.C∊»  # full program
       »  # join...
D         # implicit input...
       »  # and...
 η        # prefixes of...
D         # implicit input...
  €       # with each element...
   û      # concatenated with...
          # (implicit) current element in list...
   û      # reversed excluding the first character...
    .C    # with...
          # (implicit) each element...
    .C    # centered by spaces to length of longest element in this list (extra space on the left if unequal spaces)...
      ∊   # mirrored vertically...
       »  # by a newline
          # implicit output
```

Comment: [8 bytes](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f/f5dz2R01rDu/Wc37U0XVo9///2mAAAA) with vertical mirror `∊`.

Comment: @ovs Thanks! Added

Answer (score 1):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), <s>71</s> 61 bytes

```ruby
->n{[?+*n]+(a=(1..n).map{|x|?\s*(n-x)+?+*(x+x-1)})+a.reverse}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##DcoxDoAgDADArzi2NjQhzuhD1AENTEgIqMGAb0dvvnhtT7OqidGXeaLerwRagWT2yIcOpeY6LakHLzLSHyBTFhJfJM3R3CYm87ZwnamzvGvnYMD2AQ)

Answer (score 1):

## PHP, 103 bytes

```php
for(;$i++<$argn;$s.="
".str_pad(str_pad("",$i*2-1,"+",2),$argn*2-1," ",2))echo"+";echo"$s
",strrev($s);
```

Run as pipe with `-nR´ or [try it online](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/3199ee83cc4499000c1f8a1fbc808ef40170311d).

Answer (score 1):

## [PowerShell](https://github.com/TryItOnline/TioSetup/wiki/Powershell), 58 bytes

```powershell
param($n)'+'*$n;1..$n+$n..1|%{" "*($n-$_)+"+"*$_+"+"*--$_}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8gvTy0qzkjNyfn/vyCxKDFXQyVPU11bXUslz9pQT08lT1slT0/PsEa1WklBSQsoqasSr6mtpK2kpRIPpnSBArX///83AwA)

Simply a loop-up and -down, each iterating outputting the appropriate number of spaces and then the appropriate number of plus signs. Ho-hum.

Answer (score 1):

## [F# (Mono)](http://www.mono-project.com/), 123 bytes

```fs
let d n=
 let t n=String('+',n)
 let s n=t(n*2-1)
 [1..n]@[n.. -1..1]|>Seq.fold(fun a x->a+sprintf"\n%*s"(n+x-1)(s x))(t n)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JY1NCoMwEEb3PcUQEBPThKZ7pXdwaV0ISUpBJ7aTggXvnk5x93h8P5HMkjCVtAaE/ks5LGUOGTxge4I/ZaY@v5/4kLWuz6gOTayzxOZqHJvBWYvjbUBrwTC7ce/68LIxzV7GD8IEm@kmTSsP5SjuWDUkJOqN65JgU0rykSoe3AX2Do4cgqhIlB8)

Comment: Welcome to PPCG.

Comment: [This doesn't appear to work.](https://tio.run/##JY1LCsIwFEXnXUUIlL60JhjnBvfQYe2gYCNCvam@CBl07zHV2eFwP571MyDkvMxR4GyP1Q479vH9wJ2a1BygfpaLjYT2pK2qBmsMxssAY4QubMfN9fPL@LDcyH8gJpG0mzpey0z08oq6ZUnoUmkTi6QUlRu1uX8AsmaZ8xc) Also, input should be taken from STDIN, a file, or a function argument. We don't allow pre-assigned variables as input.

Comment: @mbomb007 Can you approve it now?

Comment: @HenrikHansen : Why is this giving an error ? `/home/runner/code.fs(2,10): error FS0039: The value or constructor 'String' is not defined.
Cannot open assembly 'code.exe': No such file or directory.`

Comment: @HenrikHansen : great the error is gone but now `Main module of program is empty: nothing will happen when it is run
`. You should probably look into it as well

Comment: @MuhammadSalman You can include(open) certain standard libraries or provide the full namespace path. I anticipated that is was alright to anticipate that the System library is loaded.

Comment: @HenrikHansen : I don't know anything about F#. Except its name. Maybe this will help : https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/16116/tips-for-golfing-in-f

Comment: @HenrikHansen The error is because of the first line. You should read input `n` from STDIN. [What's the best way to read from stdin?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40918760/2415524). Either that, or the syntax for a multiline function is wrong. I don't know F#.

Comment: @HenrikHansen : I suggested an edit. Take a look

Answer (score 1):

## PHP 102 bytes

```php
for($r=str_pad;$i++<$a;$s.="\n".$r($r("",$i*2-1,"+",2),$a*2-1," ",2))echo"+";echo"$s\n",strrev($s);
```

Ik know it can be much smaller than this ;) Greetz  mangas

Comment: Welcome to PPCG!

Comment: Your code seems to produce an error when I try to run it?

Comment: Why did you suggest this as a separate edit? It makes no sense.

Comment: @StephenLeppik : Oops , probably a mistake on my part. Soory

Answer (score 1):

## [Yabasic](http://www.yabasic.de), 102 bytes

An anonymous function that takes input as a unary number with `+` tally marks and outputs to the console.

```vb
Input""s$
n=Len(s$)
?s$
For i=-n To n
j=Abs(i)
If i For k=2To j?" ";Next:?Mid$(s$+s$,1,2*(n-j)+1)
Next
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##q0xMSizOTP7/3zOvoLRESalYhSvP1ic1T6NYRZPLHshzyy9SyLTVzVMIyVfI48qydUwq1sjU5PJMU8hUAMll2xoBZbLslRSUrP1SK0qs7H0zU1SA2rWLVXQMdYy0NPJ0szS1DTW5QLL//2trawMA)

#### Alternate Version, 117 bytes

An anonymous function answer that takes input as a decimal integer and outputs to the console.

```vb
Input""n
For i=1To n s$=s$+"+"Next
?s$
For i=-n To n
j=Abs(i)
If i For k=2To j?" ";Next:?Mid$(s$+s$,1,2*(n-j)+1)
Next
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##q0xMSizOTP7/3zOvoLRESSmPyy2/SCHT1jAkXyFPoVjFtlhFW0lbyS@1ooTLvlgFKqubpwCS58qydUwq1sjU5PJMU8hUAMll2xoBZbLslRSUrEGarOx9M1NUNICmFKvoGOoYaWnk6WZpahtqcoFk//83BgA)

Comment: Anonymous functions? They look like whole programs to me...

Comment: @ØrjanJohansen this term, for Yabasic, only means that they are not wrapped as a user defined `sub`routine, are not part of any library and thus cannot be called discretely like builtin functions can be (eg. `Abs(x)`) . You can read a bit more about this [here](http://www.yabasic.de/yabasic.htm#ref_sub) if you like.

Answer (score 1):

## [sed 4.2.2](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/), 69

Score includes +1 for the `-r` option to sed.

```
h
y/1/+/
p
x
s/1\B/ /g
y/1/+/
p
:
s/ \+/+++/p
t
p
:a
s/\+\+/ /p
ta
d
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K05N@f8/g6tS31BfW5@rgKuCq1jfMMZJX0E/HSFoBRRUiNHW19bW1i/gKgGJJAKFYrSBYgogkUQuoCmGQPAvv6AkMz@v@L9uEQA)

Answer (score 1):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), 59 bytes

```ruby
->i{[?+*i,b=(1..i).map{|c|' '*(i-c)+?+*(2*c-1)},b.reverse]}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KypNqvyfZvtf1y6zOtpeWytTJ8lWw1BPL1NTLzexoLomuUZdQV1LI1M3WVMbKK1hpJWsa6hZq5OkV5RallpUnBpb@7@gtKRYIS3aOPY/AA)

Answer (score 1):

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org), 183 bytes

```javascript
a=x=>{g='\n';r=(m,n)=>String.prototype.repeat.call(m,n);k='+';l=r(k,x)+g;c=d='';for(i=0;i++<x;c+=r(' ',x-i)+r(k,i)+r(k,i-1)+g,d+=r(' ',i-1)+r(k,x+1-i)+r(k,x-i)+g);console.log(l+c+d);}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NYxBDsIgFESv4g7Ip41N3H2/l3DrhgASLAKhxNQYz46VpKvJZN6bh3qpRRef6xCTsa0pWunyccRukWEh/pRR0OVai49uzCXVVN/ZjsVmq@qoVQgdwZkYMAxU@CxXAQ41GWIM76lwT0f0AOcVNWwAOzC5Dl7An91jmDZJmn3vvX/BtKPdcQJ1iksKdgzJ8QAajMBvU/wk2g8)

Updated my answer thanks to **@JoKing**

Comment: @JoKing sorry, my mistake, I just update my answer, thank you my friend.

Comment: @JoKing, thank you for your time

Answer (score 1):

## [APL (Dyalog Unicode)](https://www.dyalog.com/), 25 [bytes](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9429/43319)<sup>[SBCS](https://github.com/abrudz/SBCS)</sup>

```apl
⍪∘⊖⍨c,⍨⌽1↓[2]c←↑,\⎕←⎕/'+'
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT///qKM97f@j3lWPOmY86pr2qHdFsg6QeNSz1/BR2@Roo9jkR20THrVN1Il51DcVxOybqq@urQ7S9p8zjcuY61HvGi4gwwTGMIUxzEAMAA)

Explanation:

```apl
⍪∘⊖⍨c,⍨⌽1↓[2]c←↑,\⎕←⎕/'+'  ⍝ Full program
                       ⎕/'+'  ⍝ Get input from user as N, replicate '+' N times
                    ⎕←        ⍝ Print above string
                  ,\           ⍝ Find all prefixes of above string, e.g. '+','++','+++' etc.
                 ↑             ⍝ Mix the above into a matrix - right-pads with spaces as needed
               c←              ⍝ Assign above matrix to 'c' for 'corner'
          1↓[2]                ⍝ Drop the first column
        ⌽                     ⍝ Reverse the resulting matrix
     c,⍨                      ⍝ Append 'c' to above - this gives us the top half
⍪∘⊖⍨                         ⍝ Take the above, flip it about the horizontal axis,
                              ⍝ and append it to itself
```

Comment: `1↓[2]` -> `0 1↓` or even better: `c,⍨⌽1↓[2]c←` -> `⍉(⊖⍪1↓⊢)⍉`

Answer (score 1):

## [Canvas](https://github.com/dzaima/Canvas) (v8), <s>8</s> 5 [bytes](https://github.com/dzaima/Canvas/blob/master/files/chartable.md)

```
［］↔╪∔
```

[Try it here!](https://dzaima.github.io/Canvas/?u=JXVGRjNCJXVGRjNEJXUyMTk0JXUyNTZBJXUyMjE0,i=KysrKys_,v=8)

Takes input as unary using `+` as tally.

The other Canvas answer here uses v2.

Comment: Seems to be the exact same algorithm as my answer! `D` → `∔`, `η»` → `［］`, `€û.C∊` → `↔╪`.

Comment: @Makonede I grabbed the prefixes idea from your answer actually, but the rest I'll call convergent evolution ;)

Answer (score 1):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal) `j`, 6 bytes

```
¦ʁøĊmJ
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyJqIiwiIiwiwqbKgcO4xIptSiIsIiIsIisrKysrKyJd)

### How?

```
¦ʁøĊmJ
¦      # Prefixes of implicit input
 ʁ     # Palindromize each
  øĊ   # Center
    m  # Mirror each
     J # Join the (implicit) input with this
```

Comment: Input must be an integer.

Comment: @Shaggy https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/162798/diamond-creator#comment394399_162798 several other answers do this too

Answer (score 0):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt) [`-R`](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/14339/), <s>18</s> <s>16</s> 15 [bytes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1)

```
õÈç+²Ãû ê ÕiUç+
```

[Try it](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&flags=LVI&code=9cjnK7LD%2byDqINVpVecr&input=OA)

Answer (score 0):

## Java 11, <s>159</s> <s>155</s> <s>154</s> 153 bytes

```java
n->{var r="";for(int i=n,j;i-->0;r+=i>0?"\n":"")for(j=-n;++j<n;)r+=(j<0?-j:j)<n-i?"+":" ";return"+".repeat(n)+"\n"+r+"\n"+new StringBuffer(r).reverse();}
```

-5 bytes thanks to *@ceilingcat*.

**Explanation:**

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##nZBBT8QgEIXv/ooJJwjSNDF6WEqbeHcvHtUDdqkBu9NmSmvMpr@90m2PejGBkOF7j7xHsJNV4fS51K0dBniyHi83AB6jo8bWDo7rCPAcyeMH1DwRQKHT5Zx2WkO00ddwBAQDC6ryMlkCMozppqOr3hu8DdorVeaapPFlXrFXZAfGxCoJRqGWMhSoRcI8FHmlwiGIApWvmExCYJpcHAnTlJHrnY0chVxfkbQd6L72lI9j0zjiJJJycjQ4LvS86C1uP763Ke6eeur8Cc6pNN@sL29W7IW/h@jOWTfGrE8ktsgxq/mduHb/lf9NVuf9v50PYv/vefkB)

```java
n->{                       // Method with integer parameter and String return-type
  var r="";                //  First-line String, starting empty
  for(int i=n,j;i-->0      //  Loop `i` in the range (n,0]
      ;                    //    After every iteration:
       r+=i>0?"\n":"")     //     Add a new-line, unless it's the last iteration of `i`
    for(j=-n;++j<n;)       //   Inner loop `j` in the range (-n,n]
      r+=                  //    Append the result with:
         (j<0?-j:j)        //     If the absolute value of `j`
         <n-i?             //     is smaller than the input `n` minus `i`:
              "+"          //      Append a "+"
             :             //     Else:
              " ";         //      Append a space " " instead
  return"+".repeat(n)+"\n" //  Return the input `n` amount of "+", plus a new-line,
        +r+"\n"            //  plus the result-String, plus another new-line,
        +new StringBuffer(r).reverse();}
                           //  plus the result-String again reversed
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Attache](https://github.com/ConorOBrien-Foxx/attache), 62 bytes

```
{"+"*_+lf+UnGrid!Bounce=>"+ "[Table[`>,1:_]|>~`'#Reverse|>@N]}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SywpSUzOSP2fZmX7v1pJW0krXjsnTTs0z70oM0XRKb80LznV1k5JW0EpOiQxKSc1OsFOx9AqPrbGri5BXTkotSy1qDi1xs7BL7b2v19qakpxtEpBQXJ6LFdAUWZeSUhqcYlzYnFqcXQ10NA0xfhaHYVoYx1THbPY2P8A)

A lambda which takes the integer as an argument.

### Example

```
A> n := 3
3
A> Table[`>,1:n]
 false false false
  true false false
  true  true false
A> Table[`>,1:n]|>~`'#Reverse
  true  true false
  true false false
 false false false
 false false false
  true false false
  true  true false
A> Table[`>,1:n]|>~`'#Reverse|>@N
 1 1 0
 1 0 0
 0 0 0
 0 0 0
 1 0 0
 1 1 0
A> "+ "[Table[`>,1:n]|>~`'#Reverse|>@N]
 " " " " "+"
 " " "+" "+"
 "+" "+" "+"
 "+" "+" "+"
 " " "+" "+"
 " " " " "+"
A> Bounce=>"+ "[Table[`>,1:n]|>~`'#Reverse|>@N]
 " " " " "+" " " " "
 " " "+" "+" "+" " "
 "+" "+" "+" "+" "+"
 "+" "+" "+" "+" "+"
 " " "+" "+" "+" " "
 " " " " "+" " " " "
A> UnGrid!Bounce=>"+ "[Table[`>,1:n]|>~`'#Reverse|>@N]
"  +  \n +++ \n+++++\n+++++\n +++ \n  +  "
A> lf+UnGrid!Bounce=>"+ "[Table[`>,1:n]|>~`'#Reverse|>@N]
"\n  +  \n +++ \n+++++\n+++++\n +++ \n  +  "
A> "+"*n+lf+UnGrid!Bounce=>"+ "[Table[`>,1:n]|>~`'#Reverse|>@N]
"+++\n  +  \n +++ \n+++++\n+++++\n +++ \n  +  "
A> Print[_]
+++
  +
 +++
+++++
+++++
 +++
  +
["+++\n  +  \n +++ \n+++++\n+++++\n +++ \n  +  "]
A>
```

Answer (score 0):

## T-SQL, 152 bytes

[Per our IO rules](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2447/default-for-code-golf-input-output-methods/5341#5341), input is taken via pre-existing table **t** with a integer field **n**.

```sql
DECLARE @n INT,@ INT=1,@k INT=1SELECT @n=n FROM t
PRINT REPLICATE('+',@n)a:PRINT SPACE(@n-@)+REPLICATE('+',2*@-1)IF @=@n SET @k-=1SET @+=@k IF @>0GOTO a
```

Manual counting loop, not very "SQL-like". Formatted:

```sql
DECLARE @n INT,@ INT=1,@k INT=1
SELECT @n=n FROM t
PRINT REPLICATE('+',@n)
a:
    PRINT SPACE(@n-@)+REPLICATE('+',2*@-1)
    IF @=@n SET @k-=1
    SET @+=@k
IF @>0 GOTO a
```

Answer (score 0):

## [V](https://github.com/DJMcMayhem/V), 20 bytes

```
é+ÄÀ­ñ>GMÙX2é+ÄHñÄÒ+
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/v///BK7cMthxsOrT280c7d9/DMCCOwiMfhjUDhSdr///83BgA)

Hexdump:

```
00000000: e92b c4c0 adf1 3e47 4dd9 5832 e92b c448  .+....>GM.X2.+.H
00000010: f1c4 d22b                                ...+
```

Explanation:

```
é+                      " Insert a '+' character
  Ä                     " Duplicate this line
   À­                   " 'arg' - 1 times...
     ñ          ñ       " Repeat the following code:
      >G                "   Indent every line
        M               "   Move to the center line
         Ù              "   Duplicate this line
          X             "   Delete the first character of it (the space)
           2é+          "   Insert two '+' characters
              Ä         "   Duplicate this new line we made
               H        "   Return to the first line
                 Ä      " After the loop is over, duplicate the top line
                  Ò+    " Replace every character on this line with a '+'
```

Answer (score 0):

## Excel VBA, 89 bytes

Anonymous VBE immediate window function that takes input as a unary number with `+` tally marks from range `[A1]` (ie `[A1]="++++"`) that outputs to the VBE immediate window.

```vb
?[A1]:n=[Len(A1)]:For i=-n To n:i=i-(i=0):j=Abs(i):?Spc(j-1)Mid([A1&A1],1,2*(n-j)+1):Next
```

#### Alternate Version, 96 bytes

Anonymous VBE immediate window function that takes input as a decimal number from range `[A1]` that outputs to the VBE immediate window.

```vb
?[Rept("+",A1)]:For i=[-A1]To[A1]:i=i-(i=0):[B1]=Abs(i):?Spc([B1]-1)[Rept("+",2*(A1-B1)+1)]:Next
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Phooey](https://github.com/ConorOBrien-Foxx/Phooey), 82 bytes

```
&.@@($c43-1)&>&1<[-1$c10@[-1$c32]&>@[-1$c43]&+2<][!$c10@[-1$c32]&+1>-2@[-1$c43]&<]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8jIz0@t/P9fTc/BQUMl2cRY11BTzU7N0CZa11Al2dDAAUwbG8Wq2UGYJsaxatpGNrHRiqjS2oZ2ukYIJTax//@bAgA)

Phooey is an extended form of [Foo](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Foo), adding input, sane loops, and some helper functions.

Answer (score 0):

## [Swift](http://rextester.com/l/swift_online_compiler), <s>218</s> 169 bytes

Sadly, I could not use `map` instead of for loops, since it timed out.

```
func r(i:Int)->String{var l="";for j in(0...i*2){for k in(0..<i*2-1){l+=j==0&&k<i||j>0&&(j>i ?j-i-1:i-j)...(j>i ?i*3-1-j:i+j-2)~=k ?"+":" "};if j<i*2{l+="\n"}};return l}
```

Prettyfied:

```
func r(i: Int) -> String {
    var l = "";
    
    for j in (0 ... i * 2) {
        for k in (0 ..< i * 2 - 1) {
            l += (j == 0 && k < i) ||
            (j > 0 && (j > i ? j - i - 1 : i - j) ... (j > i ? i * 3 - 1 - j : i + j - 2) ~= k) ? "+" : " "
        }
        
        if j < i * 2 {
            l += "\n"
        }
    }
    
    return l
}
```

[Try it online!](http://rextester.com/XIPB10806)

Answer (score 0):

## [Retina](https://github.com/m-ender/retina/wiki/The-Language), 35 bytes

```
¶<,-2`\+
 
\+` (\++)$
$&$%"$1++
^O`
```

Takes unary `+` as input

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0otycxLNPz//9A2Gx1do4QYbS4FrhjtBAWNGG1tTRUuFTUVVSUVQ21trjj/hP//tbW1AQ)

Answer (score 0):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), <s>18 17 14</s> 13 bytes

```
”+ẋṄ¹Ƥz⁶ŒBṚ;$
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ASgA1/9qZWxsef//4oCdK@G6i@G5hMK5xqR64oG2xZJC4bmaOyT/w4dZ//8z)

-1 byte thanks to Erik the Outgolfer

```
”+ẋṄ¹Ƥz⁶ŒBṚ;$
”+                  '+' literal
  ẋ                 repeat this <input> number of times: '+++'
   Ṅ                print this string + a new line
    ¹Ƥ              get the prefixes: ['+', '++', '+++']
      z             transpose and fill with...
       ⁶            space (' '). yields ['+++', ' ++', '  +']
        ŒB         palindromize each row: ['+++++', ' +++ ', '  +  ']
          Ṛ;$      reverse and append with itself.
```

Comment: [`” ` -> `⁶`](https://tio.run/##ASgA1/9qZWxsef//4oCdK@G6i@G5hMK5xqR64oG2xZJC4bmaOyT/w4dZ//8z)

Comment: @EriktheOutgolfer of course, thanks

Answer (score 0):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), <s>141 139 137 135</s> 126 bytes

Another approach borrowing from [the other R answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/162930/80010) to this challenge by [ngm](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/79980/ngm) as well as [this other answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/164980/80010) from [Kirill L.](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/78274/kirill-l):

```r
function(n)cat(c(g(n),format(sapply(c(1:n,n:1),function(i)g(2*i-1)),j="c",w=2*n-1)),sep="
")
g=function(x)intToUtf8(rep(43,x))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PYpBCsIwEEX3PUXJaqZMF2lFpJhb1AOU0AkRnYQ00nr6GATd/fffS4Xba1/4JTb7ICBolwwWXF3EIT0rbUuMj3c99SQkk67il3t0MHS@14h0N8oq2s3QyZe3NRrVKGyc@fcHeslzuGW@QFojnEY6EAvDGcsH)

Below a fully recursive solution growing the initial line and the diamond at each step:

```r
function(n)cat("
",intToUtf8(rbind(t(f(n)[c(1:n,n:1),-1]),13)),sep="")
f=function(n)"if"(n,{cat("+");rbind(cbind(32,f(n-1),32),43)},43)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TcwxDsIwEAXR3sfYar/YFI5BQkG@BakQBRhsudmgYCqUsxsTGpppRnpzTb7Gl4aSJ2VFuBQmQ5K1HKexxD3P16w3LhzbPQW2g4oOFtLZM8Q6QJ73hyeCif4PohyJVd4ruCEcfk5Y63ppXNcU10O2Dss3NbGDSbxD/QA)

Answer (score 0):

## [CJam](https://sourceforge.net/p/cjam), 34 bytes

```
q~:X,'+X*n{_X-~' *\2*)'+*+}%_W%+:n
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S85KzP3/v7DOKkJHXTtCK686PkK3Tl1BK8ZIS1NdW0u7VjU@XFXbKu//fxMDAA)

Still wrapping my head around CJam, could probably be improved.

Answer (score 0):

## [MY-BASIC](https://github.com/paladin-t/my_basic), 126 bytes

An anonymous function that takes input as a unary number with `+` tallys

```vb
Input"",s$
n=Len(s$)
Print s$;
For i=-n To n
j=Abs(i)
If i Then 
For k=2 To j
Print" "
Next
Print Mid(s$+s$,1,2*(n-j)+1);
Next
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LcyxCsIwEIDh/Z7iCBkSkwztWjK4CAUVh76A1YjX4lV6EfTpo1b37/9vr9AfhU6ltHx/ZKW8aOC4TWxEWzjMxBlFN7CZZqQYGLsJGYa47sWQhfaChN01MS5ijPUXDL9QoYJ9eub/Zkfnz9SJ9pWvV4bDYF1lm4WU4px7Aw)

Answer (score 0):

## [uBASIC](https://github.com/EtchedPixels/ubasic), 114 bytes

```
0input"",s$:n=len(s$):?s$:fork=2ton:t$=t$+" ":nextk:fork=0-nton:f=abs(k):iffthen?mid$(t$+s$+s$,n-f+1,2*n-f)
1nextk
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JYvBCoMwEETv/YoS9pB0I6jHQPBb1GZpSLuW7gr9@zRWGHgMb2ZfZslrrX3m967GeIHA8ZnYCrgwtUbbp8RRNw4KUQHN1QROXy2n6Ts@HMV5EVtcyET6SDy98h1sm8sRzx3h4Mdbo7sM/3utiPgD)

Answer (score 0):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), 111 bytes

Rather than having two loops (one for [0..i-1] and [i-i..0]), I loop for 2*i iterations and compute the offsets from 0 for the first half and from 2*i for the last half. `printf()` takes care of the spacing!

```c
f(i,j,k){char s[9999];for(memset(s,43,j=2*i+1),k=-1;printf("%*.*s\n",i+k,~k?2*k+1:i,s),--j;)k=(j>i)?2*i-j:j-1;}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XY07DsIwDED3niICIcWpgwiwQGk5CDCU0I8T2qKmsCC4ekjZwNPzs56sZaW1n1Krr/dLwXZuuFA3r7PoR13p/O96aqvgfMkJDVp46jrvmTtswpySsut5UzSuGLjD9QpNuhQUK0CbSpXcQjyUfDITc@GO7QQptvi2@6WwsdoSOkApTQI25SYjCJ6k2ZpQvnwoWZNTy0fI@0rj97EQgR/AnhFjVPLxkClggYaOxvVxUCeAJHp5rxYf)

Comment: Suggest `x-~x` instead of `2*x+1` and `j>i` instead of `(j>i)`

Answer (score 0):

## Oracle SQL, 166 bytes

```
select decode(x,1,lpad('x',n,'x'),lpad(' ',n-y,' ')||lpad('x',2*y-1,'x'))from(select level x,abs(trunc((level-2)/n)*(2*n+1)+1-level)y,n from t connect by level<2*n+2)
```

Test in SQL*PLus (This table is used as an input `create table t(n) as select 5 from dual`)

```
SQL> set pages 0 lines 2000 feedback off
SQL> select decode(x,1,lpad('x',n,'x'),lpad(' ',n-y,' ')||lpad('x',2*y-1,'x'))
  2  from(select level x,abs(trunc((level-2)/n)*(2*n+1)+1-level)y,n from t connect by level<2*n+2)
  3  /
xxxxx
    x
   xxx
  xxxxx
 xxxxxxx
xxxxxxxxx
xxxxxxxxx
 xxxxxxx
  xxxxx
   xxx
    x
```

Answer (score 0):

## [C# (Visual C# Interactive Compiler)](http://www.mono-project.com/docs/about-mono/releases/5.0.0/#csc), 105 bytes

```cs
n=>new int[2*n+1].Select((_,i)=>new String('+',i<1?n:i>n?4*n-2*i+1:2*i-1).PadLeft(i<1?0:i>n?3*n-i:n+i-1))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Jcy9DoIwFAXgnacgLLS0EIu6FCiTJhoHEwYHNQZLNTfBawIlPn7lZznL@c7Rfax7cPsBdQ5o@WGHw8d09bM1eW87wLdSfuMXDguF5ueP5ppGyMQ9qUxrtCXkwYEuZTUPSMhCDrkoUYLCchNhnEbAhBwzFjQ5183JvCyZyGom65GARDbV1GWed@nAGrLcJccvIAluGPCGbCmlmfsD)

The idea is to create an enumerator with length equal to the number of returned lines. Iterate over the enumerator and return strings of `+` characters with varying padding dependent upon the current index in the enumeration.

```cs
// n is the diamond size
n=>
  // create an array to iterate over
  new int[2*n+1]
  // this version of select includes an index
  .Select((_,i)=>
    // create the diamond body
    new String('+',i<1?n:i>n?4*n-2*i+1:2*i-1)
    // pad according
    .PadLeft(i<1?0:i>n?3*n-i:n+i-1))
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Wolfram Language (Mathematica)](https://www.wolfram.com/wolframscript/), 97 bytes

```
d[n_]:=Column[Row/@(Drop[Prepend[DiamondMatrix[n][[All,2;;]],Table[1,n]],{n+2}]/.{1->"+",0->""})]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Dc3LCsIwEEDRf8lKaWof7iyKYreCiLthkNEEGkgmIaQolH57zOqe3XWUJu0omQ/lrIBfeDhevZ0dw8N/m/NmjD7APeqgWcFoyHlWN0rR/IAR4GKt7IcBUT7pbTV0kosXrvoVm93S1SdRCdmWiHWL5bDHnOsQDac/)

Answer (score 0):

## [Zephyr](https://github.com/dloscutoff/zephyr), 241 bytes

```python
input n as Integer
set s to""
for i from 1to n
set s to"+"+s
next
print s
for i from 1to n*2
set s to""
if i>n
set r to(i-n)-1
else
set r to n-i
end if
for j from 2to(n-r)*2
set s to"+"+s
next
for j from 1to r
set s to" "+s
next
print s
next
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZY6xDsIwDET3fMUpE6XK0A6M7HwGEg4YgRM5QaL8fEipRCN19Pnu3X0o3iYthSW@MgTnhJNkupKaRBkJOVhrfFAwvIYnhhwg66@3fTJC72yislRx492PLYk9@LjktSo7dtK5wdAj0V@EODYkF7D/0e4Lbax2cdq1wLW@Mc61zXxsJs5HKYcv)

Not having a string multiplication operator really hurts here.

#### Ungolfed/commented

```python
# Input number
input n as Integer

# Build string of that many plusses in s
set s to ""
for i from 1 to n
  set s to s + "+"
next
# Output it
print s

# Output diamond
for i from 1 to n * 2
  # Build string for each line in s
  set s to ""
  # Set r to the number of spaces on the current line: n-1, ... , 1, 0, 0, 1, ... , n-1
  if i > n
    set r to (i - n) - 1
  else
    set r to n - i
  end if
  # Add that many spaces to s
  for j from 1 to r
    set s to s + " "
  next
  # Add (n - r) * 2 - 1 plusses to s
  for j from 2 to (n - r) * 2
    set s to s + "+"
  next
  # Output it
  print s
next
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Regenerate](https://github.com/dloscutoff/Esolangs/tree/master/Regenerate), 70 bytes

```
(\+{$~1})(
( {#3-1}! {#1-1})(\+\+$4!\+)){#1}(
( $6!)(\+{#7-2}!$4)){#1}
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72qKDU9NS-1KLEkdVF07IKlpSVpuhY33TRitKtV6gxrNTW4NBSqlY11DWsVgbShLkgoRjtGW8VEMUZbUxMoVAtSomKmCBKvVjbXNapVVDGByEBMgxq6ONoMZj4A)

#### Explanation

For clarity, space is replaced with `_` and newline is replaced with `¶` in the explanation.

```
(\+{$~1})
```

Group 1: Repeat `+` a number of times equal to the input.

```
(¶...){#1}
```

Group 2 generates the top half of the diamond. Repeat it (length of group 1) times. It contains groups 3 and 4.

```
(_{#3-1}!_{#1-1})
```

Group 3: Add spaces, one less than the last time we matched group 3; or, if group 3 hasn't been matched yet, one less than the length of group 1.

```
(\+\+$4!\+)
```

Group 4: Add plusses, two more than the last time we matched group 4; or, if group 4 hasn't been matched yet, a single plus.

```
(¶...){#1}
```

Group 5 generates the bottom half of the diamond. Repeat it (length of group 1) times. It contains groups 6 and 7.

```
(_$6!)
```

Group 6: Add spaces, one more than the last time we matched group 6; or, if group 6 hasn't been matched yet, none.

```
(\+{#7-2}!$4)
```

Group 7: Add plusses, two less than the last time we matched group 7; or, if group 7 hasn't been matched yet, copy the last match of group 4.