# Diamond with numbers

Tags: code-golf, ascii-art

Inspired by [**this**](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/134184/java-diamond-with-numbers), print an ascii diamond pattern built using `0-9`.

**Rules**

- Input `n` should be between `0-9`, anything outside that range is undefined
- The diamond should be padded with spaces
- The middle line should always have no padding and be the only line to contain `n`, in the center
- Print to stdout
- As always, this is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf)

**Test Cases**

- n = 0

```
0
```

- n = 1, print

```
 0 
010
 0
```

- n = 2, print

```
  0  
 010 
01210
 010 
  0
```

- n = 9, print

```
         0
        010
       01210
      0123210
     012343210
    01234543210
   0123456543210
  012345676543210  
 01234567876543210 
0123456789876543210
 01234567876543210
  012345676543210
   0123456543210
    01234543210
     012343210
      0123210
       01210
        010
         0
```

Comment: Unfortunately, someone already had the [same challenge idea](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/8696/20260).

Comment: @xnor Wait - I don't think it's a duplicate. That asked you to print that ***specific diamond*** -- it was a k-complexity question. The answers will vary because this is asking you to generate it.

Comment: @xnor I've seen this before and usually it's a far enough distinction.

Comment: I'm not sold that the input makes a big difference, but I'll retract my dupehammer and let people vote. In particular, it seems to me like a lot of the answers could change their parameter 9 to an input.

Comment: I also feel like this is a duplicate, in the sense that answerers here could, in many cases, reasonably just look at the previous challenge’s solutions and replace a `9` by an `input()` or something.

Comment: Starting from 0 might make a difference in messing up the arithmetic trick that `1111*1111=1234321`, though I think that's unfortunate because it's a cool strategy. Is there something new that's allowed by the zeroes?

Comment: I also think its a dup, but for now withholding my dupe hammer

Answer (score 2):

## Vitsy, 50 bytes

I don't think I'm done golfing yet!

```
VVHr1mV{V2*1+\[2m]
:Xru
v&VvD([D\[' 'O]]-H1ml\NaOY
```

Explanation:

```
VVHr1mV{V2*1+\[2m]
V                  Pop n, set n as the global final variable (GFV).
 V                 Push the GFV to the current stack.
  H                Pop n, pop o, push each item of the range from o to n.
   r               Reverse the current program stack.
    1m             Call the method on line index 1.
      V{           Push the GFV to the bottom of the current stack.
        V2*1+      Push the GFV*2+1 to the stack.
             \[  ] Pop n, do the stuff in brackets n times.
               2m  Call the method on line index 2. Note that this is necessary due
                   to an unknown bug.

:Xru
:                  Clone the current stack, pushing a second stack to the stack 
                   stack and jumping to it.
 X                 Pop n and discard.
  r                Reverse the current stack.
   u               Pop the current stack and concatenate it to the previous.

v&VvD([D\[' 'O]]-H1ml\NaOY
v                  Pop n, save as a temporary variable.
 &                 Push a new stack to the stack stack and jump to it.
  V                Push the GFV.
   v               Push the temp var, clear the temp var memory.
    D([        ]   If the top item is not zero, do the stuff in brackets.
                   This is necessary as all loops always apply once.
       D\[' 'O]    Peek n, output n spaces.
   -               Pop n, pop o, push o-n.
    H              Pop n, pop o, push each item of the range from o to n.
     1m            Call the method at line index 1.
       l\N         Output all numbers in this stack.
          aO       Output a newline.
            Y      Pop and discard the current stack from the stack stack.
```

[Try it online!](http://vitsy.tryitonline.net/#code=VlZIcjFtVntWMioxK1xbMm1dCjpYcnUKdiZWdkQoW0RcWycgJ09dXS1IMW1sXE5hT1k&input=&args=OQ)

Comment: That was SpOOky as hell I didn't realize you deleted it

Comment: @Insane Yeah, I made a one byte error. :P Fixed now.

Comment: @Insane Explanation added.

Comment: @Insane [Try this with input `40`. ;)](http://vitsy.tryitonline.net/#code=VlZIcjFtVntWMioxK1xbMm1dCjpYcnUKdiZWdkQoW0RcWycgJ09dXS1IMW1sXE5hT1k&input=&args=NDA)