# Output a Magical 8 Trapezium

Tags: code-golf, kolmogorov-complexity

Your task is to output a Magical 8 Trapezium:

```
        1 × 8 + 1 = 9
       12 × 8 + 2 = 98
      123 × 8 + 3 = 987
     1234 × 8 + 4 = 9876
    12345 × 8 + 5 = 98765
   123456 × 8 + 6 = 987654
  1234567 × 8 + 7 = 9876543
 12345678 × 8 + 8 = 98765432
123456789 × 8 + 9 = 987654321
```

- Output in your chosen language in the fewest bytes possible.
- Note the number of spaces at the start of each line to maintain the trapezium shape.
- Trailing spaces are allowed.
- You can use `×` or the letter x - whichever you prefer.

Comment: [Related.](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/8696/8478) (slightly...)

Comment: Middle spaces are required, yes?

Comment: @KevinLau-notKenny it is, but you could always post an alternative too if it's significant.

Comment: It's 6 bytes corresponding to the 6 spaces in the middle, so no, I don't think it's significant enough.

Answer (score 15):

### Python 2, 59 bytes

```python
a=i=1
exec"print'%9d x 8 +'%a,i,'=',a*8+i;i+=1;a=a*10+i;"*9
```

The numbers `a` and `i` the equation `a * 8 + i` are generated arithmetically. Each line, `i` is incremented, and `a` has the next digit appended via `a=a*10+i`. For example, if `a=12345, i=5`, then `i` becomes `6`, so the new `a` is `12345*10 + 6` which is `123456`.

Storing these as numbers rather than strings lets us compute the RHS as given by the equation `a*8+i`, which is shorter than string reversing.

Comment: +1 for seeing this for what it is - a sum that can be generated

Answer (score 7):

## [V](https://github.com/DJMcMayhem/V), 37 bytes

```
i¸ 1 X 8 + 1 = 98ñYp|Eylp^Xf+$ylp
```

[Try it online!](http://v.tryitonline.net/#code=acK4IDEgWCA4ICsgMSA9IDkbOMOxWXB8RXlscAFeWGYrASR5bHAY&input=)

This contains unprintable, so here is a hexdump:

```
00000000: 69c2 b820 3120 5820 3820 2b20 3120 3d20  i.. 1 X 8 + 1 = 
00000010: 391b 38c3 b159 707c 4579 6c70 015e 5866  9.8..Yp|Eylp.^Xf
00000020: 2b01 2479 6c70 18                        +.$ylp.
```

Answer (score 5):

## Pyth, 32 bytes

```
VS9ss[*dK-9NSN" x 8 + "N" = "r9K
```

[Try it online!](http://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=VS9ss%5B%2adK-9NSN%22+x+8+%2B+%22N%22+%3D+%22r9K&debug=0)

```
VS9ss[*dK-9NSN" x 8 + "N" = "r9K
VS9                                  # For N in 1..9
   s                                 # Join without delimiter
    s[                               # Reduce the array on + (flattens)
      *dK-9N                         # - Space, repeated K=(9-N) times
            SN                       # - The string sequence 1..N
              " x 8 + "              # - This string literal
                       N             # - N itself
                        " = "        # - This string literal
                             r9K     # - The string sequence 9..K
```

---

Thanks to @FryAmTheEggman for saving 2 bytes.
Thanks to @KennyLau for saving 3 bytes.

Comment: `s` does not join with space - it joins with no delimiter.

Comment: @isaacg hah, and now I'm thinking I could save a byte by joining with space

Comment: The byte-count would be [the same](http://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=VS9tjd%5B%2adK-9NjkSN%22x+8+%2B%22N%5C%3Djkr9K&debug=0).

Answer (score 5):

## [05AB1E](http://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), <s>32</s> <s>31</s> <s>30</s> 28 bytes

Code:

```
TG9N-ð×NLJðN"x8+ÿ="€ðJžmN£J,
```

Uses the **CP-1252** encoding. [Try it online!](http://05ab1e.tryitonline.net/#code=VEc5Ti3DsMOXTkxKw7BOIng4K8O_PSLigqzDsErFvm1OwqNKLA&input=).

Comment: `.c` isn't usable here?

Comment: @carusocomputing It is, but that postdates the challenge.

Comment: Ahhh... Did not see the timestamp.

Answer (score 5):

### PHP, <s>105</s> <s>89</s> <s>60</s> 57 bytes

my first golf try here (thanks to manatwork & user55641)

```
for(;$i++<9;)printf("%9s x 8 + $i = %s
",$s.=$i,$s*8+$i);
```

#### 59

```
for(;$i++<9;)printf("%9s x 8 + $i = %s
",$s.=$i,$t.=10-$i);
```

#### 89 (my own try)

```
for(;@++$i<=9;){printf("%9s x 8 + %s = %s\n",join(range(1,$i)),$i,join(range(9,10-$i)));}
```

#### 105 (first)

```
for($j='123456789';@$j[$i++];){printf("%9s x 8 + %s = %s\n",substr($j,0,$i),$i,strrev(substr($j,-$i)));}
```

Comment: No need for the braces around a single statement. The $i alone better interpolate directly in the string without format specifier.

Comment: You can drop 23 more bytes with a few tricks: 
Changing @++$i<=9 to $i++<9 saves 2 bytes. You don't need to silence notices as they don't stop execution and under standard PPCG rules you can ignore stderr if you want to.
Changing the \n to an actual newline character saves a byte.
Changing the join(range(...)) bits to $s.=$i and $t.=10-$i saves 15 bytes. This works because assignments return the value assigned  and is pretty much the most valuable trick I've found for golfing php.
The last 5 bytes are detailed by manatwork above

Comment: You can drop 2 more bytes by replacing `$t.=10-$i` with `$s*8+$i`. https://tio.run/##K8go@G9jXwAk0/KLNKxVMrW1bSytNQuKMvNK0jSUVC2LFSoULBS0FVQyFWwVVIu5lHRUivVsVTKBlJaFtkqmpvX//wA

Comment: That´s 59 bytes. And `$s*8+$i` instead of `$t.=10-$i` saves two more.

Answer (score 4):

### CJam, <s>39</s> <s>38</s> 36 bytes

*Thanks to Optimizer for saving 2 bytes.*

```
9{)_,:)9Se[" x 8 + "@S'=S9_,fm4$<N}/
```

[Test it here.](http://cjam.aditsu.net/#code=9%7B)_%2C%3A)9Se%5B%22%20x%208%20%2B%20%22%40S'%3DS9_%2Cfm4%24%3CN%7D%2F)

Same byte count:

```
9{)_,:)9Se[]"x8+"+:\'=9_,f-Y$<]S*n}/
```

This requires the latest version, available on [Try it online!](http://cjam.tryitonline.net/#code=OXspXyw6KTlTZVtdIng4KyIrOlwnPTlfLGYtWSQ8XVMqbn0v&input=)

Comment: @Optimizer lived up to his name, then!

Answer (score 4):

## Python 2, <s>87</s> <s>84</s> <s>78</s> 75 bytes

```python
s="123456789"
n=1
exec'print"%9s"%s[:n],"x 8 + %s ="%n,s[::-1][:n];n+=1;'*9
```

[**Try it online**](http://ideone.com/nr9mEO)

A previous version uses some string magic.

```python
R=range(1,10)
for n in R:print" "*(9-n)+`R`[1:n*3:3]+" x 8 + %d = "%n+`R`[-2:27-3*n:-3]
```

Casting `range(1,10)` to a string gives `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]`, and this is nice since every number is only a single digit. So getting the string `123456789` from this is simple with `` `range(1,10)`[1::3] ``. The reversed range is  `` `range(1,10)`[-2::-3] ``. Then, to get only as far as I want each iteration, I slice it off at either `3*n`, or at `3*(9-n)` (`27-3*n`) for the reversed digits.

Comment: You can do `for n in range(1,10):print"%9s"%s[:n]+" x 8 + %s = "%n+s[::-1][:n]` for 80 bytes.

Comment: `s="123456789";n=1;exec'print"%9s"%s[:n],"x 8 + %s ="%n,s[::-1][:n];n+=1;'*9` saves three more! Down to 75.

Comment: Nice, thanks for the help! Too bad I had to double-slice the second time...

Answer (score 4):

## Ruby, <s>77</s> <s>73</s> <s>65</s> 60 bytes

[Try it online~](https://repl.it/Cfhi/37)

Major revamps from @manatwork

Another overhaul from @xsot

```
a=i=0;9.times{puts"%9d x 8 + %d = %d"%[a=a*10+i+=1,i,a*8+i]}
```

Comment: Seems to be shorter with format string: `puts'%9d x 8 + %d = %d'%[k=[*1..i]*'',i,k.to_i*8+i]`.

Comment: `(1..9).map` → `1.upto(9)`

Comment: Ah, I didn't know about `%9d` being a formatting option to pad integers like that

Comment: 60: `a=i=0;9.times{puts"%9d x 8 + %d = %d"%[a=a*10+i+=1,i,a*8+i]}`

Comment: @xsot that's great! Didn't think of calculating the initial number like that.

Answer (score 4):

## Java 10, <s>151</s> <s>133</s> <s>130</s> <s>129</s> <s>126</s> 110 bytes

```java
v->{String p="\n",r="";for(int n=123456789,i=9;i>0;n/=10,p+=" ")r=p+n+" x 8 + "+i+" = "+(n*8+i--)+r;return r;}
```

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##LY/LTsMwEEX3/Yorr2ychJZnKsv9A7pBYgMsXDdFLu7EcpwIVOXbgyOymbdG55zNYMrz8Xuy3nQdXoyj6wpwlJp4MrbBfm6B1xQdfcHyt9YdMQiVp@Mqhy6Z5Cz2IOhpKHfX5TJo9kGsiJoxdWojzx9BenN3//D49FxvC6e3yu3Wim71Zl0EqRmYiDpIkgw/qCHBpMu1zpnTTS1dWQoZVWxSHwlRjZOaAUJ/8Blg4RhmvEu24P8c758wYlH47VJzqdo@VSGvkidOleXUey8Wn3H6Aw)

**Explanation:**

```java
v->{                   // Method with empty unused parameter and String return-type
  String p="\n",       //  Prefix-String, starting at a newline
         r="";         //  Result-String, starting empty
  for(int n=123456789, //  Multiply-number, starting at 123456789
      i=9;i>0          //  Loop `i` in the range [9, 0):
      ;                //    After every iteration:
       n/=10,          //     Remove the last digit from the integer
       p+=" ")         //     Append a space after the prefix
    r=...+r;           //   Prepend the following to the result-String:
      p                //    The prefix-String
      +n               //    Followed by the integer
      +" x 8 + "       //    Followed by the literal String " x 8 + "
      +i               //    Followed by the loop-index `i`
      +" = "           //    Followed by the literal String " = "
      +(n*8+i--)       //    Followed by the result of that equation
  return r;}           //  Return the result-String
```

Comment: I think you could save bytes by using `x` instead of the multiplication sign.

Comment: You can save a couple of bytes by initializing `s` to `"\n"` and removing `"\n"+` from the `for` loop

Comment: @wizzwizz4 Thanks. Should have known `×` is 2 bytes instead of 1 like `x`..

Comment: Aren't you adding `s` to the result on each iteration as well?

Comment: I know this is old, but can't you do `return o` instead of `System.out.print(o)`? Also, you can change to Java 10 and save with `var` and lambdas

Comment: @EmbodimentofIgnorance Done. This is indeed one of my earliest answers. :) Not even sure why I had the print instead of return.. xD PS: I cannot use `var` since there are two `Strings`. I could use something like `var p="\n";var r="";`, but that would be 1 byte longer instead of shorter.

Answer (score 4):

### Perl, 49 bytes

```pl
printf"%9s x 8 + $_ = %s
",$@.=$_,$_+8*$@for 1..9
```

#### Usage

```sh
perl -e 'printf"%9s x 8 + $_ = %s
",$@.=$_,$_+8*$@for 1..9'
```

Answer (score 3):

### Batch, 117 bytes

```
@echo off
set a=         12345678987654321
for /l %%i in (1,1,9)do call echo %%a:~%%i,9%% x 8 + %%i = %%a:~17,%%i%%
```

Yes, that is 16 % signs on one line; that's Batch for you!

Answer (score 3):

### C#, 113 bytes

```
void f(){for(int n=1,i=1;i<10;n=10*n+ ++i)Console.WriteLine(new string(' ',9-i)+n+" x "+"8 + "+i+" = "+(n*8+i));}
```

if you have anyway to improve this solution feel free to share.

Comment: You can save 1 byte by removing a space: `;n=10*n+ ++i` in the for-loop can be changed to `;n=++i+10*n`. Also, `+" x "+"8 + "+` can be changed to `+" x 8 + "+`. to save 3 more bytes.

Comment: void f(){for(int n=1,i=1;i<10;n=++i+10*n)Console.WriteLine($"{new string(' ', 9-i)}{n} x 8 + {i} = {(n*8+i)}");}

------------ saved you a byte!

Answer (score 2):

### PowerShell v2+, <s>85</s> <s>64</s> <s>58</s> <s>57</s> 52 bytes

```
8..0|%{" "*$_+-join(1..++$i+" x 8 + $i = "+9..++$_)}
```

Loops from 8 to 0 `8..0|%{...}` via the range operator. Each iteration, we output a string concatenation consisting of (the appropriate number of spaces `" "*$_`), plus a `-join`ed string of (a range from `1` to a pre-incremented helper number `++$i`, plus the middle bit `" x 8 + $i = "`, plus the final range from `9` to the current number `$_` pre-incremented).

One big trick here is we leverage the "left-preference" for typecasting, which allows us to "add" arrays together inside the `-join` parens, meaning we use only one `-join` operator.

#### Example

```
PS C:\Tools\Scripts\golfing> .\magical-8-trapezium.ps1
        1 x 8 + 1 = 9
       12 x 8 + 2 = 98
      123 x 8 + 3 = 987
     1234 x 8 + 4 = 9876
    12345 x 8 + 5 = 98765
   123456 x 8 + 6 = 987654
  1234567 x 8 + 7 = 9876543
 12345678 x 8 + 8 = 98765432
123456789 x 8 + 9 = 987654321
```

Comment: `%{` Are your eyes alright?

Comment: @gcampbell If your eyes looked like that, you'd be frowning, too.

Comment: Depends on how your font renders percents.

Answer (score 2):

### Haskell, 92 bytes

```
s=(show=<<)
[1..9]>>= \x->([x..8]>>" ")++s[1..x]++" x 8 + "++s[x]++" = "++s[9,8..10-x]++"\n"
```

How it works:

```
s=(show=<<)                   -- helper function that turns a list of numbers into
                              -- a string without delimiters, e.g. [1,2] -> "12"

[1..9]>>=                     -- for each number 1 to 9
     ([x..8]>>" ")            -- take length of [x..8] copies of a space
     s[1..x]                  -- the digits from 1 to x
     " x 8 + "                -- a string literal
     s[x]                     -- the digit of x
     " = "                    -- another string literal
     s[9,8..10-x]             -- the digits from 9 down to 10-x
     "\n"                     -- an a newline
```

Answer (score 2):

### Pyke, <s>30</s> 29 bytes

```
9Fd*~utj+9<\x8\+9i-\=ji>_dJ)X
```

[Try it here!](http://pyke.catbus.co.uk/?code=9Fd%2a%7Eutj%2B9%3C%5Cx8%5C%2B9i-%5C%3Dji%3E_dJ%29X&warnings=0)

```
9F                         )  -  for i in range(9):
  d*                          -       " " * i
        +                     -      ^ + V
       j                      -       j = V
    ~ut                       -        "123456789"
         9<                   -     ^[:9]
           \x8\+9i-\=         -    [^, "x", 8, "+", (9-i), "=", V]
                        _     -     reversed(V)
                     ji>      -      j[i:]
                         dJ   -   " ".join(^)
                            X - print(reversed(^))
```

Answer (score 2):

### [Retina](https://github.com/m-ender/retina), 66 bytes

Byte count assumes ISO 8859-1 encoding. The leading linefeed is significant.

```
123456789!9 = 987654321
+`^((.)+)\B.!.(.+).
 $1!$2$3¶$&
!
 x 8 +
```

[Try it online!](http://retina.tryitonline.net/#code=CjEyMzQ1Njc4OSE5ID0gOTg3NjU0MzIxCitgXigoLikrKVxCLiEuKC4rKS4KICQxISQyJDPCtiQmCiEKIHggOCArIA&input=)

Answer (score 2):

## [MATL](https://github.com/lmendo/MATL), <s>38</s> <s>36</s> 35 bytes

```
9:"9@-Z"@:!V' x 8 + '@VO61O58@:-v!D
```

[**Try it online!**](http://matl.tryitonline.net/#code=OToiOUAtWiJAOiFWJyB4IDggKyAnQFZPNjFPNThAOi12IUQ&input=)

Answer (score 2):

## C, 74 bytes

```
d(i,n){for(i=n=1;i<10;n=++i+n*10)printf("%9d x 8 + %d = %d\n",n,i,n*8+i);}
```

Answer (score 2):

## J, 51 bytes

```
(|."1|.\p),.' x 8 + ',"1]p,.' = ',"1]\|.p=:u:49+i.9
```

Creates the string `123456789` and then operates on prefixes and suffixes of it to create the output.

#### Usage

```
   (|."1|.\p),.' x 8 + ',"1]p,.' = ',"1]\|.p=:u:49+i.9
        1 x 8 + 1 = 9        
       12 x 8 + 2 = 98       
      123 x 8 + 3 = 987      
     1234 x 8 + 4 = 9876     
    12345 x 8 + 5 = 98765    
   123456 x 8 + 6 = 987654   
  1234567 x 8 + 7 = 9876543  
 12345678 x 8 + 8 = 98765432 
123456789 x 8 + 9 = 987654321
```

Answer (score 2):

## JavaScript ES6 (88)

Taking advantage of the new `repeat` method, backticks and templating...

```
i=10;for(y="";--i;)console.log(`${" ".repeat(i)+(y+=(x=10-i))} x 8 + ${x} = ${y*8+x}\n`)
```

Comment: nice job bro , you should consider to remove some space and use `alert` instead of `console.log`, it can save some bytes!

Comment: Given I answered this just before midnight I figure I was close to half asleep... I'll post an update on this soon. LOL

Answer (score 2):

## R, <s>107</s> 103 bytes

```
a=1;for(i in 2:10){cat(rep("",11-i),paste(a,"x",8,"+",(i-1),"=",strtoi(a)*8+(i-1)),"\n");a=paste0(a,i)}
```

**Ungolfed :**

```
a=1

for(i in 2:10)
    cat(rep("",11-i),paste(a,"x",8,"+",(i-1),"=",strtoi(a)*8+(i-1)),"\n")
    a=paste0(a,i)
```

**Result :**

```
        1 x 8 + 1 = 9 
       12 x 8 + 2 = 98 
      123 x 8 + 3 = 987 
     1234 x 8 + 4 = 9876 
    12345 x 8 + 5 = 98765 
   123456 x 8 + 6 = 987654   
  1234567 x 8 + 7 = 9876543 
 12345678 x 8 + 8 = 98765432 
123456789 x 8 + 9 = 987654321
```

Comment: [96 bytes](https://tio.run/##FcpNCoMwEAbQfY8xqwx@XYy/iZjDqNRioalkIvX2UZcPXsxZve6TpriG9@Mf1/Qyyy9@x2S2US@okbKqm7azDoIwPKV3DDoIFlQQAsgT1DjbtU1dlXIvZnw8zcQQzvkE)

Answer (score 2):

## [APL (Dyalog Unicode)](https://www.dyalog.com/), <s>61</s> <s>52</s> 39 [bytes](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9429/43319)<sup>[SBCS](https://github.com/abrudz/SBCS)</sup>

```apl
↑(⍳9)((¯9↑↑),' x 8 +',⊣,'= ',↑∘⌽)¨⊂1↓⎕D
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT////1HbRI1HvZstNTU0Dq23BPKASFNHXaFCwUJBW13nUddiHXVbBSADKNMx41HPXs1DKx51NRk@apv8qG@qy///AA)

-9 bytes by using the `10⊥` trick to parse the number, instead of a reduction.
Thanks to @Adám for -13!

Explanation:

```apl
↑    ((¯9↑↑),' x 8 +',⊣,'= ',↑∘⌽)¨⊂1↓⎕D
                                     ⎕D  ⍝ Numbers from 0 to 9
                                   1↓    ⍝ Drop the 0
 (⍳9)(                          )¨⊂      ⍝ Do 9 times, N=current
                             ↑∘⌽         ⍝ Reverse the string (9..1) and cut off N elements
                      ⊣                  ⍝ N itself
      (   ↑)                             ⍝ Drop N elements off the 1..9 string...
      (¯9↑ )                             ⍝ ...then pad it back with spaces
            ,' x 8 +', ,'= ',            ⍝ Join with a few constant strings
↑                                        ⍝ Format
```

Answer (score 1):

### JavaScript (ES6), 99 bytes

```
_=>[...Array(9)].map((n,i)=>`${n="        123456789".substr(i,9)} x 8 + ${++i} = ${n*8+i}`).join`\n`
_=>".........".replace(/./g,(n,i)=>`${n="        123456789".substr(i,9)} x 8 + ${++i) = ${n*8+i}\n`)
```

Where `\n` represents a literal newline character. The second version outputs a trailing newline. I came up with a formula for the numbers `('1'.repeat(9-i)+0+i)/9` but the padding was easier to do this way.

Answer (score 1):

## [Brainfuck](http://esolangs.org/wiki/Brainfuck), 232 bytes

```
++++++++[->+>+>+++++[->+>+>+>+>+>+++<<<<<<]>->>+>++>+++<<<<<<<<]>++>+>>>+++>>>---<<<<<<[-[-<<+>>>>.<<]>+[-<+>>>>+.<<<]>.>>>>>.<<<<<.>>>.<<<.>.<.>>.<<.>>>>.<<<<.<<<<[->>>+>>>+<<<<<<]>>[-<<+>>>>>>.-<<<<]>[->>>-<<<<+>]<<<[->>>+<<<]>.>]
```

[Try it online!](https://copy.sh/brainfuck/?c=KysrKysrKytbLT4rPis-KysrKytbLT4rPis-Kz4rPis-KysrPDw8PDw8XT4tPj4rPisrPisrKzw8PDw8PDw8XT4rKz4rPj4-KysrPj4-LS0tPDw8PDw8Wy1bLTw8Kz4-Pj4uPDxdPitbLTwrPj4-PisuPDw8XT4uPj4-Pj4uPDw8PDwuPj4-Ljw8PC4-LjwuPj4uPDwuPj4-Pi48PDw8Ljw8PDxbLT4-Pis-Pj4rPDw8PDw8XT4-Wy08PCs-Pj4-Pj4uLTw8PDxdPlstPj4-LTw8PDwrPl08PDxbLT4-Pis8PDxdPi4-XQ$$)

Can be golfed much further...

Answer (score 1):

### Javascript (using external library) (143 bytes)

```
n=>_.Range(1,9).WriteLine(v=>_.Range(0,10-v).Write("",x=>" ")+_.Range(1,v).Write("")+" x 8 + " + v + " = "+_.Range(10-v,v).Reverse().Write(""))
```

Link to lib: https://github.com/mvegh1/Enumerable/

Explanation of code: Create range 1 to 9, and for each value, write a line corresponding to the complex predicate. The predicate is passed the current integer value, and creates a range spanning 10-currentValue elements, in order to create that many spaces. Those spaces are concatenated with the formula part of the line, and then that is concatenated with the tailend of the range matching the number of elements as the frontend, in reverse order.

Note: In the image, the first line is off by one space because the console added a quotation mark since the return value is a string. The actual value is formatted correctly

[image]

Answer (score 1):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 24 bytes

```
9Lε©LJ'x8'+®'=T®L-Jðý}.c
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ASgA1/8wNWFiMWX//zlMzrXCqUxKJ3g4JyvCric9VMKuTC1Kw7DDvX0uY///)

Uses a newer version than the challenge, which is now allowed.

Comment: It's not much, but in the even newer version of 05AB1E you can remove the `©`, and change the `®` to `y` to save a byte.

Comment: @KevinCruijssen Eh, I don't generally "update" old answers like that. Also, the "newer version" is a totally different language (different implementations).

Answer (score 1):

## [Canvas](https://github.com/dzaima/Canvas), 20 [bytes](https://github.com/dzaima/Canvas/blob/master/files/chartable.md)

```
９｛Ｒ⤢x∙8∙+¹=¹◂±ｍ） ＊］ｒ
```

[Try it here!](https://dzaima.github.io/Canvas/?u=JXVGRjE5JXVGRjVCJXVGRjMyJXUyOTIyeCV1MjIxOTgldTIyMTkrJUI5JTNEJUI5JXUyNUMyJUIxJXVGRjREJXVGRjA5JTIwJXVGRjBBJXVGRjNEJXVGRjUy,v=8)

Answer (score 1):

## VBA (Excel), 51 bytes

Using Immediate Window

```
For z=1To 9:a=a &z:?Spc(9-z)a" x 8 +"z"="a*8+z:Next
```

Answer (score 0):

## k (77 bytes)

Could probably be shortened a bit more

```
-1@'((|t)#\:" "),'(t#\:n),'" x 8 + ",/:n,'" = ",/:(t:"I"$'n)#\:|n:"123456789";
```

Example:

```
k)-1@'((|t)#\:" "),'(t#\:n),'" x 8 + ",/:n,'" = ",/:(t:"I"$'n)#\:|n:"123456789";
         1 x 8 + 1 = 9
        12 x 8 + 2 = 98
       123 x 8 + 3 = 987
      1234 x 8 + 4 = 9876
     12345 x 8 + 5 = 98765
    123456 x 8 + 6 = 987654
   1234567 x 8 + 7 = 9876543
  12345678 x 8 + 8 = 98765432
 123456789 x 8 + 9 = 987654321
```

Answer (score 0):

## golflua, 56 characters

```
p=""~@i=1,9p=p..i; w(S.q("%9s x 8 + %d = "..p*8+i,p,i))$
```

Sample run:

```
bash-4.3$ golflua -e 'p=""~@i=1,9p=p..i; w(S.q("%9s x 8 + %d = "..p*8+i,p,i))$'
        1 x 8 + 1 = 9
       12 x 8 + 2 = 98
      123 x 8 + 3 = 987
     1234 x 8 + 4 = 9876
    12345 x 8 + 5 = 98765
   123456 x 8 + 6 = 987654
  1234567 x 8 + 7 = 9876543
 12345678 x 8 + 8 = 98765432
123456789 x 8 + 9 = 987654321
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Object Pascal (FPC)](https://www.freepascal.org/), <s>156</s> <s>127</s>  103 bytes

Trivial solution, <s>using the Format library func</s>. Shaved some more bytes by using only integers and no strings. Reduced in size thanks to @manatwork (for teaching me some basic stuff about writeln).

```pascal
var i,c:int64;begin i:=0;for c in[1..9]do begin i:=i*10+c;WriteLn(i:9,' x 8 + ',c,' = ',i*8+c);end;end.
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PYlBCsIwFAWv8nbVJg0tiLQJvYF7F@Ii/U3lS/kpMYi3j3XjYpiBidMzUG42/yK/NstGpbx9AmuyLPl8clN4sIDt2LolJhBYbp0xw32O@D@uu1aRuybO4SIHtoOu8EEPhUrT3uNurntFRxdk/mFK@QI)

Ungolfed:

```pascal
var
  i, c: int64;
begin
  i := 0;
  for c in [1..9] do
  begin
    i := i*10+c;
    WriteLn(i:9, ' x 8 + ', c, ' = ', i*8+c);
  end;
end.
```

Comment: Nice, but why you use `Format`? `WriteLn(i:9,' x 8 + ',c,' = ',i*8+c);` And with the price of a compiler warning you can remove `i:=0;`. (Yes, will not be compatible with some ancient Pascal versions.)

Comment: @manatwork Because I didn't know about the `:` operator... Will change it later today

Comment: I'm afraid, the `:` is not operator. Is `Write`/`WriteLn` specific field width specifier.

Comment: @manatwork Yeah thats what I meant, didn't know about it.

Answer (score 0):

## [///](http://esolangs.org/wiki////), 149 bytes

```
/:/ x 8 + //-/ = //0/1234//_/9876//|/  /||||1:1-9
||| 12:2-98
|||123:3-987
|| 0:4-_
||05:5-_5
| 056:6-_54
|0567:7-_543
 05678:8-_5432
056789:9-_54321
```

[Try it online!](http://slashes.tryitonline.net#code=LzovIHggOCArIC8vLS8gPSAvLzAvMTIzNC8vXy85ODc2Ly98LyAgL3x8fHwxOjEtOQp8fHwgMTI6Mi05OAp8fHwxMjM6My05ODcKfHwgMDo0LV8KfHwwNTo1LV81CnwgMDU2OjYtXzU0CnwwNTY3OjctXzU0MwogMDU2Nzg6OC1fNTQzMgowNTY3ODk6OS1fNTQzMjE)

Answer (score 0):

## [dc](https://www.gnu.org/software/bc/manual/dc-1.05/html_mono/dc.html), 79 bytes

```
1[32P]sS[d0<S1-d0<R]sR[dZ9r-lRxrdn[ x 8 + ]PdZn[ = ]Pdd8*rZ+prd10*dZ+dZA>M]dsMx
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0n@/98w2tgoILY4ODrFwCbYUBdIBsUWB0WnRFkW6eYEVRSl5EUrVChYKGgrxAakRAE5tiBGioVWUZR2QVGKoYFWSpR2SpSjnW9sSrFvxf//AA)

Somewhat better than I expected. Started with a solution that juggled stack and an incremental register before realizing I only need to keep the left-most number around - since the value to be added is the number of digits the left-most number has, this can be determined via `Z` and the result can just be calculated according to the formula.

`[32P]sS[d0<S1-d0<R]sR` feels wasteful, but I couldn't come up with a much better way to handle the indentation. The main macro, `[dZ9r-lRxrdn[ x 8 + ]PdZn[ = ]Pdd8*rZ+prd10*dZ+dZA>M]dsMx` should be fairly self-explanatory based on my above description. The initial `1` just seeds the whole thing.

Answer (score 0):

## Pyth - 30 bytes

First attempt, working on optimization.

```
VS9+*dK-9Njd[jkSN\×8\+N\=jkr9K
```

[Try it online](http://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=VS9%2B%2adK-9Njd%5BjkSN%5C%C3%978%5C%2BN%5C%3Djkr9K&debug=0).

Answer (score 0):

## [Forth (gforth)](http://www.complang.tuwien.ac.at/forth/gforth/Docs-html/), 76 bytes

```forth
: f 0 10 1 do cr 10 * i + dup 9 .r ."  x 8 + "i . ." = "dup 8 * i + . loop ;
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LYpBCoAwEAO/MvSoWPRWFV9jWS0ILUXB369dEALJJJFc73M4xEx1QRiZmoiZvVrsSPTEpzDjK97BS2iVS3jDDWdr@J@eK@fCqqIf)

#### Explanation

Start a value at 0. Starts a loop from 1 to 9. Each iteration:

- Multiply value by 10 and add the loop index
- output this value right-aligned
- output " x 8 + "
- output the loop index
- output " = "
- calculate results and output

#### Code Explanation

```forth
: f                  \ start word definition
  0                  \ set up counter/value
  10 1 do            \ start a counted loop from 1 to 9
    cr               \ output a newline
    10 * i +         \ calculate the next value for the first term
    dup 9 .r         \ make a copy and then output in a right-aligned space of 9 characters
    ."  x 8 + "      \ output " x 8 +"
    i .              \ output the loop index
    ." = "           \ output " ="
    dup 8 * i +      \ perform the actual calculation
    .                \ output result
  loop               \ end the counted loop
;                    \ end the word definition
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Perl 6](https://github.com/nxadm/rakudo-pkg), 58 bytes

```perl6
my $a;printf "%9s x 8 + $_ = %s\n",$a~=$_,$a.flip for 1..9
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH7/z@3UkEl0bqgKDOvJE1BSdWyWKFCwUJBW0ElXsFWQbU4Jk9JRyWxzlYlHkjppeVkFiik5RcpGOrpWf7/DwA)

Answer (score 0):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal) `C`, 24 bytes

```
`%x8+%=%`Ṅ9ɾ:ṅḂ"v¦$wY∩v%
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyJDIiwiIiwiYCV4OCslPSVg4bmEOcm+OuG5heG4glwidsKmJHdZ4oipdiUiLCIiLCIiXQ==)

```
`%x8+%=%`                 # Take the string "%x8+%=%"
         Ṅ                # Join by spaces
                       v% # Replace %s in this with each of...
                      ∩   # Transposed..
                     Y    # Interleave...
           9ɾ:     $w     # 1...9 and...
           9ɾ ṅ           # "123456789"
               Ḃ"v¦       # Prefixes and reversed suffixes
```

Answer (score 0):

## JavaScript, 70 bytes

```js
alert = console.log; // for less frustration

for(n='1';m=n%10;n+=++m)alert(n.padStart(9)+` x 8 + ${m} = `+(n*8+m));
```