# Tips for golfing in jq

Tags: code-golf, tips

Since jq is the [Language Of The Month for September 2021](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/23836/language-of-the-month-for-september-2021-jq/23837#23837), what general tips do you have for golfing in [jq](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/)? I'm looking for ideas which can be applied to code-golf problems and which are also at least somewhat specific to jq (e.g. "remove comments" is not an answer).

Please post one tip per answer.

Answer (score 10):

## Use try-// instead of if-then-else

<s>`if A then B else C end`</s>

The conditional expression is very lengthy and almost never<sup>1</sup> worth it. Depending on your condition `A` and the values `B` and `C` there might be short alternatives based on indexing or arithmetic, but a general solution is to use `try` and `//`.

`try` is part of the try-catch exception handler, and returns `empty` for faulty code if the `catch` part is omitted.
`//` is the *alternative* operator which returns the left hand side if it evaluates to a truthy<sup>2</sup> value, and the right hand side otherwise.

Putting these two together we can rewrite the conditional expression as:

```
(try(A//C)*1//B)
```

The `*1` assumes `C` is a number or a string, for lists you might need `+[]` instead and if C is a stream of multiple values, this gets a bit trickier. The outer parentheses can be removed in some cases.

The idea is that `A//C` returns `true` if `A` is `true`, and `true*1` throws an error, which is caught by `try`.

This can be shortened further by using `EXP ?`, which should be a shorthand for `try EXP`, though it seems like it does a lot more stuff, for example causing all subsequent filters to not throw errors. In this case `(1?*(A//C)//B)` works, but you might need to do some trial and error in your specific situation.
Note that `?//` is its own operator since 1.6, so you need to add a space there.

---

**Practical example: Fibonacci**

A recursive filter using a conditional expression comes in at [41 bytes](https://tio.run/##yyr8/z8lNU0hzSozTc/GqCQjNU9PITWnODVaT9dQR0/XqCYttiYxJUUhNS/F@n9RYl56qoahgWZN2v9/@QUlmfl5xf9184oA):

```
def f:if.<2then. else[.-1,.-2|f]|add end;
```

Applying the general approach gets this to [39 bytes](https://tio.run/##yyr8/z8lNU0hzaqkqFJDz8ZIX18jWk/XUEdP16gmLbYmMSVFU1PLUF9fz/p/UWJeeqqGoYFmTdr/f/kFJZn5ecX/dfOKAA):

```
def f:try(.<2//([.-1,.-2|f]|add))*1//.;
```

In this case `add` can be used to throw an error in the truthy case, [35 bytes](https://tio.run/##yyr8/z8lNU0hzaqkqFJDz8ZIXz9aT9dQR0/XqCYttiYxJUVTX1/P@n9RYl56qoahgWZN2v9/@QUlmfl5xf9184oA):

```
def f:try(.<2//[.-1,.-2|f]|add)//.;
```

Using `?` instead of `try` for [33 bytes](https://tio.run/##yyr8/z8lNU0hzUpDz8ZIXz9aT9dQR0/XqCYttiYxJcVeU19fz/p/UWJeeqqGoYFmTdr/f/kFJZn5ecX/dfOKAA):

```
def f:(.<2//[.-1,.-2|f]|add?)//.;
```

<sub><sup>1</sup> If you have a practical example where this is not the case, I'd like to see it.</sub>

<sub><sup>2</sup> Falsy values are `null` and `false`; all others are truthy. `empty` represents the empty stream - the absence of a value.</sub>

Comment: Looking at [this answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/235085/64121) by Lynn, it might be possible to do `((A//C)*1? //B)` instead. Will update this answer later

Comment: Best tip so far! You can even do `(1?*(A//C)//B)`.

Comment: @MichaelChatiskatzi that's nice. Do you know why this works? All I can find in the manual and github wiki is that `?` is a postfix operator. (Even `((1?)*(A//C)//B)` works)

Comment: I am really not sure how this works. I believe it is definitly a postfix operator but in these cases on `1` and not the whole expression. And as long as `1?` is not used it won't be evaluated? That would be my best guess.

Comment: @MichaelChatiskatzi It seems like `?` works for the whole line and breaks `//` in later filters: [`(1?)|0|././/1`](https://tio.run/##yyr8/1/D0F6zxqBGT19PX9/w//9/@QUlmfl5xf9184oA). That's some strange behaviour

Comment: putting `?` left of parentheses works

Comment: `?` either takes an expr `a<op>b` or a thing in parens, it seems. the manual says it is identical to `try`.

Comment: @Razetime but it is somewhat unintuitive what parts the `?` affects. For example `(1?)|0|././/1` seems to be equivalent to `try(1|0|././/1)`. And [`(./.? //1)*0|./.`](https://tio.run/##yyr8/z8lNak0vUZDT1/PXkFf31BTy6AGyP7/35DL4F9@QUlmfl7xf90iAA) only throws an error for `0`, I'm not sure how you would achieve with `try` instead of `?`

Answer (score 6):

## Consult Secret Reference

**Spoiler: [github.com/stedolan/jq/wiki/](https://github.com/stedolan/jq/wiki/)**

JQ has a tutorial & manual on the [official site](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/), both of which I highly recommend!

However, on the github repo, there's an extensive wiki on the language with loads more info sure to help your golfing.

It includes:

- FAQ section with:

  - Unofficial tutorials
  - Editor bindings, including vim & emacs
  - Language bindings, including Python & Java
  - Interactive playgrounds for JQ
- Sections for:

  - Processing invalid json
  - Modules
  - Cookbook
  - Implementation details for numbers, regex and other built-ins
- Other goodies

  - Lazy evaluation, generators and backtracking
  - Implement finite state machines in JQ?!

Answer (score 6):

## Avoid `split`

When used on a string, the `/` operator behaves exactly like `split`, but is shorter by at least 3 bytes - and sometimes by as much as 7, such as when going from `now|todate|split(":")` to `now|todate/":"`

Answer (score 5):

## Sugary JSON

##### Overview

Instead of `{foo:.foo, bar:.bar}`, use `{foo, bar}`.

In both case, we're creating a new JSON object with the key `foo` mapping to the value of `foo` in the input.

#### Example

```
CODE:  {a, c}

IN:    {"a": 1, "b": 2, "c": 3, "d": 4}
OUT:   {"a": 1, "c": 3}
```

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##yyr8/786UUchuRZIKyUqWRnqKCglKVkZAalkJStjIJWiZGVSCwA)

Comment: Similarly, {foo: $foo} => {$foo}

Answer (score 4):

## Pipe + Dot = Smell

They're sometimes needed, but this is often a code (golf) smell. You should be wary of any pipes followed by an expression containing a dot.

*Or could it be possible to rewrite every jq program with a period into one without?*

#### Examples

`[99|range(.)]` -> `[range(99)]`

Answer (score 3):

## Avoid map()[]

Ungolfed: `[1,2,3]|map(.+1)[]`

Golfed: `[1,2,3][]|.+1`

or even better: `1,2,3|.+1`

Will add more here!

Answer (score 2):

If the coding challenge calls for dealing with individual characters in the input using `explode` can be handy.  It breaks a string into an array of codepoints, allowing you pipe the results to a loop to process each character.