# Generate recursive "arrays" up to a certain depth

Tags: code-golf, array, json

Given a positive integer `n`.

Generate a JSON array (can be a string, or your language's built-in JSON representation as long as we can get valid JSON, (your code does not need to include outputting the string, you can just use the built-in JSON representation)) containing two empty JSON arrays, then, add a set of 2 empty JSON arrays to each existing set of 2 empty JSON arrays up to `n` deep. `n` can be 0 or 1 indexed.

## Rules

1. The shortest code wins the challenge (as this is code-golf).
2. All output JSON must be RFC8259 compliant.

## Examples

```
Input: 0
Output: [[], []]
Input: 1
Output: [[[], []], [[], []]]
Input: 2
Output: [[[[], []], [[], []]], [[[], []], [[], []]]]
```

Comment: Welcome to Code Golf! I've added the [tag:code-golf] and [tag:array] tags.

Comment: `-1` should give `[]` then, no?

Comment: Can we take 1-indexed input, to `1` gives `[[],[]]` etc.?

Comment: @Adám The integer must be positive, so the number -1 is out of the question. And no, you must start the index at 0. I will update the post to state that.

Comment: I wasn't saying that `-1` should be a valid input, just that if we run the transformation rule in reverse from `[[],[]]` we get `[]`. Also, this community enjoys having input rule lax, and it is common to allow both 0-indexing and 1-indexing.

Comment: Oh. Sorry I'm new to the community, just learning the ropes here.

Comment: Your description of the task is confusing (at least to me), and is not recursive as the title implies. Let's say `n=2`. So we begin by generating two empty arrays. Then we need to "add a set of 2 empty JSON arrays to each existing set of 2 empty JSON arrays that are `n` deep". But there are no arrays that are `n` deep. So we stop? Please reword, and maybe include a worked out example with all intermediate steps

Comment: I'm assuming there's a wording error and the "that are `n` deep" really means "any empty array UP to `n` deep?"

Comment: I consider the "as long at it can be converted to an RFC8259 compliant JSON string" to be an invitation for rule-bending.  The native outputs for nested lists in R or Vyxal are different from the JSON format, but they can clearly be converted into JSON format using additional code.  But so can many other things, including simply the input number itself...  how much unscored additional code should we allow to do the conversion, and how different can the output be from a JSON string be before we accept that the additional code is actually performing the majority of the task...?

Comment: @DominicvanEssen I've widened the scope of the question, is this what you mean?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal), 4 bytes

```
›(W:
```

[Try it online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyJBIiwiIiwi4oC6KFc6IiwiIiwiMVxuMlxuMyJd) One-indexed. Returns a nested list.

```
›    # increment
 (   # repeat for n+1 times (n+1 is popped):
  W  #   wrap stack into single list (initially [])
   : #   duplicate
     # implicit output
```

---

#### [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal) `W`, 3 bytes

```
(W:
```

[Try it online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyJBVyIsIiIsIihXOiIsIiIsIjFcbjJcbjMiXQ==)

Here, it repeats `n` times, and before outputting implicitly, the `W` flag wraps the stack into a single list.

Answer (score 6):

## [APL (Dyalog Extended)](https://github.com/abrudz/dyalog-apl-extended), <s>12</s> 6 bytes

−6 thanks to OP now allowing 1-indexing and results that *can* be converted to JSON, rather than the JSON itself.

Full program; prompts for 1-indexed `n` and prints APL nested array equivalent of the required JSON. Adding an print handler which just converts output to JSON shows the required result.

```apl
⍮⍨⍣⎕⊢⍬
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT9dNrShJzUtJTfkfUJSZV/KobUL1o76pQApIegX7@z3q3VXLBWQHu@rl5wWnFhdn5ufBVKqDGepcjzraC/4/6l33qHfFo97FIO1dix71rvkPFP@vAAYFXIZcMJYRnGUMZ5kAAA)

`⍬` empty list (`[]`)

`⍣⎕⊢` on that, apply the following function `n` (prompted-for) number of times:

`⍮⍨` pair up with itself

The print handler:

`Print←{`…`}` assign a function as follows:

`⎕JSON⍺` convert output array to JSON

`⎕←` print that

Setting up the JSON printing callback on output:

`⎕SE.` for the current session:

`onSessionPrint←` set the event handler for printing to

`Print` call the above handler function

Answer (score 4):

## [GNU sed](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/), <s>36</s> 35 bytes

I believe numeric input is allowed to be in unary format for sed. For ex. `3` becomes `@@@` and `0` becomes the empty string (no @s). The nameless label `:` is supported by older versions of sed.

```sed
s:$:@[]:
:
s:@::
s:\[]:[&, &]:g
/@/b
```

[Try it online with sed 4.2.2!](https://tio.run/##K05N@f@/2ErFyiE61orLiqvYysEKRMYAudFqOgpqsVbpXPoO@kn//3M5cDmAkAMA)

In each loop iteration one character is removed from the unary number as one depth is introduced in the array. A small trick is used in the first line, where the initialization is only `[]` (shorter than `[[], []]`), like a "-1 based indexing". As such the input number is incremented by one with the extra `@`. This helps also with not checking up front for the empty string (input 0).

**EDIT:** with 1-based indexing now allowed, the incrementing from first line isn't needed,thus saving one byte: `s:$:[]:` Thanks to Adám for the heads-up.

Comment: I think you can skip the incrementing, as 1-based indexing is now OK.

Answer (score 3):

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org), <s>25</s> <s>23</s> 22 bytes

*Saved 2 bytes thanks to [Arnauld](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/58563/arnauld)! Saved 1 byte by changing to 1-indexed.*

```javascript
f=n=>n--?[a=f(n),a]:[]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0osSyxOLsosKNHNy09J/f8/zTbP1q4uT1fXPiFapTo60TZNI09TJzG2NjbBKiE6NuF/cn5ecX5Oql5OfrpGmoaBpqY1F6qQIaaQEVDoPwA) Arnauld's observation of testing for 1-indexed as `~n--` saves 1 byte over `n--+1`.

Returns an array of arrays, which, when printed, will output JSON compliant arrays.

If a string output is mandatory, then we have, using the same method:

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org), <s>34</s> <s>32</s> <s>31</s> 29 bytes

*Saved 2 bytes thanks to [Arnauld](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/58563/arnauld)! Saved 2 bytes thanks to [l4m2](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/76323/l4m2)! Saved 1 byte by changing to 1-indexed.*

```javascript
f=n=>`[${n--?[a=f(n),a]:[]}]`
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0osSyxOLsosKNHNy09J/f8/zTbP1i4hWqU6T1fXPjrRNk0jT1MnMdYqOrY2NuF/cn5ecX5Oql5OfrpGmoahpqY1F6qQEaaQMVDoPwA)

Comment: [29 string output](https://tio.run/##y0osSyxOLsosKNHNy09J/f8/zTbP1i4hWqU6T1fXPjrRNk0jT1MnMdYqOrY2NuF/cn5ecX5Oql5OfrpGmoahpqY1F6qQEaaQMVDoPwA)

Comment: @l4m2 thanks!!!

Answer (score 3):

## [sclin](https://github.com/molarmanful/sclin), 15 bytes

```
[]"dup ,";1+ *#
```

[Try it here!](https://replit.com/@molarmanful/try-sclin) I've been thinking about having code that took input from the next line rather than the previous. Surprisingly useful, gonna have to use it more often...

For testing purposes:

```
[]"dup ,";1+ *# f>o
2
```

### Explanation

Prettified code:

```
[] ( dup , ) ; 1+ *#
```

- `[]` empty list
- `(...) ; 1+ *#` execute (next line) + 1 times...

  - `dup ,` duplicate and pair into list

Answer (score 3):

## TI-Basic, 32 [bytes](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4764/98541)

```
Prompt N
"[]
For(I,0,N
"["+Ans+","+Ans+"]
End
Ans
```

[image]

Comment: Can you not remove `Prompt N` and replace `N` with `Ans`?

Comment: no, since I use `Ans` for the string, and adding `->Str1` everywhere would be longer I think

Comment: But wouldn't `For(` read the value of `Ans` once and for all, before the string concatenation overwrites `Ans`?

Comment: yes but I need to initialize `Ans` to  `"[]"` before the loop

Answer (score 2):

## [Retina](https://github.com/m-ender/retina/wiki/The-Language), 22 bytes

```
K`[]
"$+"+`\[]
[[],[]]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0otycxLNPz/3zshOpZLSUVbSTshBsiKjo7ViY6N/f/fGAA) No test suite due to the way the program uses history. Explanation:

```
K`[]
```

Replace the input with an empty array.

```
"$+"+`
```

Repeat `n` times...

```
\[]
[[],[]]
```

... replace each empty array with a pair of empty arrays.

Previous 0-indexed version was 27 bytes:

```
K`[[],[]]
"$+"+`\[]
[[],[]]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0otycxLNPz/3zshOjpWJzo2lktJRVtJOyEmOpYLKvL/vxEA) No test suite due to the way the program uses history. Explanation: Starts with the first pair of empty arrays thus reducing the number of iterations needed by 1.

Comment: 1-indexing is now OK.

Answer (score 2):

## ><>, 58 bytes

```
e0i1+:?v"]["oo~.
3[r]40.\"["o:1-20
.","o:1-303[r]40
."]"o~
```

[Try it](https://mousetail.github.io/Fish/#eyJ0ZXh0IjoiZTBpMSs6P3ZcIl1bXCJvb34uXG4zW3JdNDAuXFxcIltcIm86MS0yMFxuLlwiLFwibzoxLTMwM1tyXTQwXG4uXCJdXCJvfiIsImlucHV0IjoiXHUwMDAwIiwic3RhY2siOiIiLCJtb2RlIjoibnVtYmVycyJ9)

Offsetting the number by 1 would save 2 bytes, since I can skip the 1+.

### Explanation

[image]

Top row: Main function. Check if the recursion level is 0, if so print `[]` and return, else go down.

Second row: print `[`, then recurse.

Third row: print `,` then recurse

Print `]` and return.

Comment: OP has updated the spec, and you can probably remove the `1+` now.

Answer (score 2):

## [FunStack](https://github.com/dloscutoff/funstack) alpha, 23 bytes

```
Pair self iterate "" At
```

You can try it at [Replit](https://replit.com/@dloscutoff/funstack). Takes the depth (1-indexed) as a command-line argument and the program on stdin.

#### Explanation

At the core of this solution is the following infinite sequence:

```
[]
[[],[]]
[[[],[]],[[],[]]]
...
```

We start with the empty list, and each subsequent element is two copies of the previous element wrapped in a list. `Pair self` does exactly that, and we get the desired infinite list by `iterate`ing that function starting from `""` (empty string / empty list).

This creates a bare value at the left end of the program, so it is appended to the program's argument list. Then `At` takes the first argument as an index into the second argument and returns the corresponding element.

Answer (score 1):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 11 bytes

```
Ｆ⊕Ｎ≔Ｅ²υυ⭆¹υ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S85ILErOT8z5/z8tv0hBwzMvuSg1NzWvJDUFyC4oLfErzU1KLdLQ1NRUcCwuzkzP0/BNLNAw0lEo1QRha66Aosy8Eo3gEiCVDpIyBAlrWv//b/RftywHAA) Link is to verbose version of code. Explanation: Port of Adám's APL answer.

```
Ｆ⊕Ｎ
```

Loop `n+1` times...

```
≔Ｅ²υυ
```

... replace the predefined empty list with a list of two copies of it.

```
⭆¹υ
```

Pretty-print the final list (needed because Charcoal doesn't normally output anything for empty lists).

Comment: You can probably change to looping `n` times, now with OP's updated spec.

Comment: @Adám Not worth my while editing my answer just for that one byte (`⊕`) saving though.

Answer (score 1):

## [Python](https://www.python.org), 29 bytes

```python
g=lambda n:n*[0]and[g(n-1)]*2
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72soLIkIz9vwYKlpSVpuhZ7021zEnOTUhIV8qzytKINYhPzUqLTNfJ0DTVjtYwgam4qFxRl5pVopGsYampywdhGSGxjTU2IUpixAA)

1-indexed. Returns Python's native array representation.

## [Python](https://www.python.org), 45 bytes

```python
g=lambda n:n and f'[{g(n-1)},{g(n-1)}]'or'[]'
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72soLIkIz9vwYKlpSVpuhY3ddNtcxJzk1ISFfKs8hQS81IU0tSjq9M18nQNNWt1YIxY9fwi9ehYdagm5YKizLwSjXQNQ01NLhjbCIltrKkJUQqzBwA)

Returns a string, also 1-indexed. I found three different 45-byte functions for this, so I chose the simplest.

Answer (score 1):

## [QuadR](https://github.com/abrudz/QuadRS), 8+2=10 bytes

Takes `n` as 1-indexed argument on TIO.

```regex
.+
[&,&]
```

Initial input:

```regex
[]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KyxNTCn6/19PmytaTUct9v//6Nj/RgA)

`.+` match everything (any number of any characters)

`[&,&]` replace with open-bracket, match, comma, match, close-bracket

Answer (score 1):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), 5 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```
¯IƒD‚
```

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//0HrPY5NcHjXM@v/fCAA) or [verify all test cases](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/W98bJKfvZLCo7ZJCkr2/w@t9zs2yeVRw6z/tTr/AQ).

**Explanation:**

```python
¯      # Push an empty list: []
 Iƒ    # Loop the input+1 amount of times:
   D   #  Duplicate the current list
    ‚  #  Pair the two lists together
       # (after the loop, output the result implicitly)
```

Comment: Do you really need `I`?

Comment: @Adám Well, I could use `s` as alternative. ;) But the input has to be the top of the stack in order to start the loop.

Answer (score 1):

## [PHP](https://php.net/), 64 bytes

```php
for($a=[],$b=[&$a,&$a];$argn--;)$a=[$a,$a];echo json_encode($b);
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8go@G9jXwAk0/KLNFQSbaNjdVSSbKPVVBJ1gDjWWiWxKD1PV9daEyQHFASJpSZn5CtkFefnxafmJeenpGqoJGla//9v9C@/oCQzP6/4v64bAA)

I thought this solution by reference elegant enough to be posted, I wish we could use a reference to a variable while initializing it, but unfortunately it's not the case. Too bad for the output format, almost a third of the code is lost to formatting..

Answer (score 1):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org), <s>57</s>  53 bytes

*Edit: saved 4 bytes by copying [MarcMush's approach](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/255519/95126)*

```
\(n){s="[]";for(i in 1:n)s=paste0("[",s,",",s,"]");s}
```

Returns JSON string.

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72waMGGotTk0qLizLLU-MSiosRK26WlJWm6FjdNYzTyNKuLbZWiY5Ws0_KLNDIVMvMUDK3yNIttCxKLS1INNJSilXSKdZR0wGSskqZ1cS1UswWaoRqGmlzoQkaYQsaaEP0LFkBoAA)

---

## [R](https://www.r-project.org), <s>41</s> 37 bytes

```
f=\(n,s={})`if`(n,f(n-1,list(s,s)),s)
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=XY5BCsIwEEX3PUWICAlEUFdSyCXcqtRQkxoJk5JJBRFP4qYu3Lv0Kt7G1NZNF8MM7__5_PsjtK-gyyagPetChaAu8tlEM1t9pkZuGQiU1xvfW7NPt2EwWwhnMTIUyHmawfxWgHIUxJY8mxAFZE1AY9QH0n3mGcbAkr0TSw9nHSKJnihyQg8kiRaqPBuUIvqi47JKZRyvVcqZM7qhwhrmNFTxmPCfo6prd2FOVFyU3jlVo5ZUUC7ojvJx5q9E379t-_0F)

Returns R nested list, which can be converted into a json string.

Answer (score 1):

## [Julia 1.0](http://julialang.org/), 21 bytes

```julia
!x=1:2(x>0).|>_->!~-x
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yyrNyUw0rPj/X7HC1tDKSKPCzkBTr8YuXtdOsU634n9afpFCpkJmnoKBlSmXAhAUFGXmleTkaWQq2NopKGZqcqXmpfwHAA)

returns a nested array

**Explanation**

- `a .|> f` applies `f` on each element of `a`
- when `x=0`, `1:0` is (kinda) an empty list, so the result is an empty list
- when `x>0`, `1:2` acts like a 2-element list, and each element of this list will be `!(x-1)`

Answer (score 1):

## [Raku](https://github.com/nxadm/rakudo-pkg), 21 bytes

```raku
{(@,{$_,$_}...*)[$_]}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH7n1uplmb7v1rDQadaJV5HJb5WT09PSzNaJT629n9xYqWCnlqaQlp@kYKhnp7pfwA)

Answer (score 1):

## [jq](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/), 36 bytes

```
def n:try(.<0//(.-1|[n,n]))+[]//[];n
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yyr8/z8lNU0hz6qkqFJDz8ZAX19DT9ewJjpPJy9WU1M7OlZfPzrWOu//fwMuQy4jAA)

Thanks to [ovs for the `try(A//C)+[]//B`](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/235138/86147) hack!

Our recursive function has a base case of `-1`, which yields `[]`. Otherwise, our input is decremented, and `[n,n]` recurses into the function twice.

Answer (score 1):

## [Thunno](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno), \$7\log_{256}(96)\approx\$ 5.76 bytes

```
ls{KDZP
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72sJKM0Ly9_wYKlpSVpuhbLc4qrvV2iAiA8qOCChUYQBgA)

Port of Kevin Cruijssen's 05AB1E answer.

##### Explanation

```python
ls{KDZP  # Implicit input
ls       # Push an empty list and swap
  {K     # Repeat (input) times:
    DZP  #  Duplicate and pair
         # Implicit output
```

Answer (score 0):

### Batch, 76 bytes

```
@set s=[]
@for /l %%i in (0,1,%1)do @call set s=%%s:[]=[[],[]]%%
@echo %s%
```

Explanation: Port of the 1-indexed version of my Retina answer, but looping from `0` to `n` to convert back to 0-indexed. `call set` is needed because otherwise the variable gets expanded before the `for` loop executes.

Comment: Sadly no savings to be made by switching to 1-indexing (change the `0` to a `1`).

Answer (score 0):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 9 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page)

```
’ßWƊR‘?;`
```

A recursive, monadic Link that accepts a non-negative integer (0-indexed) and yields the nested list. (Replace `‘` with `¹` to use 1-indexed input.)

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ASEA3v9qZWxsef//4oCZw59XxopS4oCYPztg/8OHxZLhuZj//zI)**

#### How?

```
’ßWƊR‘?;` - Link: integer, n
      ?   - if...
     ‘    - ...condition: increment (i.e. n != -1?)
   Ɗ      - ...then: last three links as a monad - f(n):
’         -    decrement (n) -> n-1
 ß        -    call this Link with n-1
  W       -    wrap that in a list
    R     - ...else: range (n = -1) -> []
        ` - use as both arguments of:
       ;  -   concatenate
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Factor](https://factorcode.org/), 33 bytes

```factor
[ { } swap [ dup 2array ] times ]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HcuxCsIwFEDR3a@4X@DQUcG1uLgUp9LhUVOMTZPw8qSI9NsjdT9nktGS1nt3vbUnFrEns9PoAqIqn8KrpHhc1ZtTfOJ8aGrPl42ySqbn8c40f8uA@cUVhjpKCFz2SlYfrf4A)